# Книга про профессиональный JavaScript

Tags: javascript, книги

Я прочитал "JavaScript руководство программиста" и потом ~год практиковался Я знаю клиентский JavaScript на уровне 7 из 10 Раньше не имел практики Ajax (небыло сервера) теперь есть "сервер" (Denwer), Учу PHP и хочу создать крупный проэкт (уже начал) где мне потребуется отличное знание КЛИЕНТСКОГО JS на уровне отличного понимания работы библиотеки JQuery (например просматривая её код узнал новые незнакомые ключевые слова (delete например) ) И уметь создавать кроссбраузерные так же использующие и современные технологии  скрипты. У меня есть "книга с носорогом" я начал её читать но она мне не понравилась...
Посоветуйте пожалуйста книгу по JS (очень желательно на русском) типа "сборник рецептов с описанием" про технологии клиента (и различии работы с ними в разных браузерах) и клиент-серверные технологии и всякие "фишки" js (Например я с удивлением узнал в википедии (о PHP) про любой_сценарий.php?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42)
PS: под

> на уровне отличного понимания работы
> библиотеки JQuery

имеется в виду знание тех принципов и методов которые использовал автор этой библиотеки при её написании, а не "умение пользоваться ею".

Comment: я как-то отвечал на подобный [вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/137586/jquery-научиться-javascript#answer-container-137602)

Comment: "крупный проэкт" - это просто классика жанра, плюсанул.

Comment: "она мне не понравилась", это единственная адекватная книга, которая затрагивает практически все аспекты языка и клиентской разработки с его использованием, либо пересмотрите свои взгляды, либо вы, в действительности, не хотите учится, если это так, то ни одна книга вам не поможет.

PS: не стоит пытаться написать крупный про**э**кт

Comment: Спасибо @Spectre прочитаю посоветаное вами, но видно всё таки придётся читать книгу с "носорогом". Но всё таки посоветуйте книгу типа "хаки разных браузеров и их использование" или "рецепты профессионального JS" просто я лучше понимаю когда вижу код а не текст :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope почему не стоит?

Comment: Никогда не понимал, почему на ХэшКоде столько вопросов в стиле *порекомендуйте самую-самую книжку по `X`.*

Comment: @Котик, так я и узнал про нужную книгу по ссылке а ссылку узнал от сюда благодаря @Spectre...

Comment: PS: Всё таки счас читаю "книгу с носорогом" - "JavaScript. Подробное руководство. 6-е издание" и всем советую :), всётаки я был не прав и "книга с носорогом" - лучшая для изучения JS для "кодеров" на моём уровне (и 6е издание написана лучше советую именной его и оно про ECMA Script 5) Это всё IMHO просто я "старожилы" правы советуя эту книгу...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> имеется в виду знание тех принципов и методов которые использовал автор этой библиотеки при её написании, а не "умение пользоваться ею".

То есть вы хотите понять как на javascript написать аналог jquery?

Для этого следует почитать в книге с 'носорогом'(Javascript - подробное руковоство Д. Фленаган 5-е издание) главы 7,8,9 Объекты и массивы, функции, классы конструкторы и прототипы.

Если не усвоить ООП, то понимание принципов работы Jquery никогда не придет, сколько ни практикуйся. А для успешного завершения серьезных самописных проектов, создающихся в одиночку, рекомендуется хорошо знать C++, так как это дает понимание функционирования высокоуровневых языков и многих концепций программирования, в том числе и ООП.

Comment: А какие ещё книги есть на тему типа "книги с носорогом"? Просто мне как то она не нравится...

Comment: Книга с носорогом ахахахах ))))) Знаем такую =) А вообще учите, учите, может Вам и учить не нравится, тогда не стоит тратить время.

Comment: JavaScript: сильные стороны Д. Крокфорд
Но там стиль изложения тоже официальный.

Эти книги как бы подразумевают что вы уже опытный программист знающий многие аспекты программной разработки.

Есть еще 
JavaScript. Библия пользователя Д. Гудман
Но она совсем для начинающих.

Еще посмотрите в магазине ozon и на торрентах есть разные книги. Почитайте пару страниц каждой, так проще понять чей стиль ближе.

Comment: PS: Всё таки счас читаю "книгу с носорогом" - "JavaScript. Подробное руководство. 6-е издание" и всем советую :), всётаки я был не прав и "книга с носорогом" - лучшая для изучения JS для "кодеров" на моём уровне (и 6е издание написана лучше советую именной его и оно про ECMA Script 5) Это всё IMHO просто я "старожилы" правы советуя эту книгу...

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря [@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre) (не зря плюсанул) нашёл как раз ту книгу которую искал -

> John Resig Pro JavaScript™ Techniques

от автора JQuery. Правда не люблю на английском читать поэтому нашёл не последнее (шестое) 2010 г. а пятое 2008 г. зато полный русский перевод:

> JavaScript. Профессиональные приемы
> программирования

Так что вопрос можно считать закрытым, спасибо всем кто участвовал в его обсуждении.

Comment: PS: Пока успел прочитать только "Об Авторе" и полистать но по моему стоит скачать на английском...

Answer (score 2):

[Маккоу А. - Веб-приложения на JavaScript [2012, PDF, RUS]](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4201240).

Comment: @zloctb и вам спасибо +1

Answer (score -1):

Книга с носорогом не нравится?

Это хорошо

Это говорит о том что ты достаточно хорошо знаешь язык

Лично я в ней нашел очень много ошибок

Что касается книг - на озоне есть книга с птичкой шаблоны javascript и еще книгу его коллеги посмотри, они оба на яхо работают - вот книги и читай

Потом можешь взять код scriptjava.net и оптимизировать под свои нужды

Главное все заверни в функции чтобы убрать код из глобальной области видимости