# Книги по JavaScript, HTML5, Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, книги

Недавно на работе столкнулся с этим замечательным языком. Понятно, что чтобы начать писать на JS достаточно прочитать несколько публикаций в блогах. Но на одних статьях не проживешь - они слишком разрозненны и непоследовательны. Поэтому хочется прочитать по книжке, для каждой из этих технологий:

1) непосредственно язык JavaScript

2) HTML5

3) Node.JS

Хотелось бы, чтобы книжки были сжатыми (без лишних отступлений), свежими и наиболее полно охватывали интересующую тему. Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: У меня создается такое впечатление, что куча народа занята поиском **"той самой-самой правильной книги,"** которую нужно прочитать, чтобы сразу всему научиться. Нравится тема - читайте все книги по теме, из плохо написанных тоже можно много чему научиться. Плюс да, поиск по `"best books for XYZ"` на `stackoverflow` еще никто не отменял.

Comment: @Котик 

>куча народа занята поиском "той самой-самой правильной книги," которую нужно прочитать

- и такая книга есть я её (их каждой в своей области) всегда долго ищу и нахожу :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148086/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-javascript)

2) см. [здесь(HTML5 - семантика)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/18060929/) и [здесь(HTML5 - js API для начинающих)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19024617/)

3) для начала освойтесь с JS, а там и за node.js можно браться.

Answer (score 3):

По javascript: [Современный учебник JavaScript](http://learn.javascript.ru/)

По HTML5 - Кристофер Шмитт, Кайл Симпсон "HTML5. Рецепты программирования"

Еще:

- [Структурная разметка с HTML5. Часть 1.](http://www.xiper.net/learn/tegofenshuj/html5/structural-markup-with-html5-1.html)
- [Структурная разметка с HTML5. Часть 2.](http://www.xiper.net/learn/tegofenshuj/html5/structural-markup-with-html5-2.html)

Answer (score 3):

Внесу свои пять копеек. По JS есть две очень хорошие книги (если их тут уже упоминали в ссылках, приведенных выше, то пардон)

1. Дэвид Флэнаган - JavaScript Подробное руководство. Книга от известного издательнства O'Reilly, на данный момент последним является 6-ое издание, у нас выходила в минувшем году.
2. Дэнни Гудман - JavaScript Библия пользователя. У этой книги я видел 5-ое издание от 2006 года, но, думаю, есть и куда более поздние версии

Comment: @DreamChild я как раз автор "указанного @Astor выше вопроса" и я могу точно сказать что книга  JavaScript Библия пользователя совершенно противоположна просьбам автора вопроса а именно - там очень много "воды"

Comment: @Rules, хм..признаться, не заметил просьбу автора про отсутствие воды) Тут вы правы, эта книга, пожалуй, не подойдет - она достаточно объемна. Как, впрочем, и вторая, та тоже не из маленьких и тоже со всеми подробностями.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что дизайн приложений — один из самых важных навыков для разработчика. Понимание паттернов, умение проектировать приложения и понимать плюсы и минусы тех или иных решений, без всякого сомнения, тот навык, который красной нитью проходит через все уроки, посты в блогах, статьи в новостных лентах и хабрахабрах, помогая объединять все эти разрозненные практики.

Я посоветую вот эту книгу — [Addy Osmani «Паттерны для масштабируемых JavaScript-приложений»](http://largescalejs.ru/). По ссылке мой перевод этой книги на русский язык. В книге обсуждается проектирование архитектуры приложений на базе паттернов «Медиатор», «Модуль» и «Фасад».

Answer (score 1):

Перечислю несколько книг и ресурсов, которые как говорится must read.

1. JavaScript - подробное руководство. 6 издание.
2. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference - подробный справочник (на русский переведен частично)
3. dmitrysoshnikov.com - очень подробное описание стандарта EcmaScript (на русском и английском)
4. perfectionkills.com - блог разработчика prototype.js
5. Cody Lindley - JavaScript Enlightenment (вышла в изд OReilly в декабре 2012 года, можно скачать бесплатную версию pdf на сайте автора)
6. John Resig - Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja (вышла в 2012 году на английском)

Этого вполне хватит для начала.
Остальные ресурсы и книги, в том числе широкоизвестные, читать пока не советую. Есть риск получить неверную информацию.