# Книги и другие материалы для обучения

Tags: книги, faq

Какие книги могут пригодиться для обучения?

## [1. Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454684/181472)

## [2. Stack Overflow на английском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454724/181472)

## [3. Programming Notes for Professionals books](https://www.goalkicker.com/) - книги, сделанные сообществом StackOverflow

## [4. EbookFoundation/free-programming-books](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books) - официально бесплатные книги на различных языках, огромный список, множество языков программирования и технологий

Это вопрос предназначен для того, чтобы в единственном общем ответе собрать ссылки на эталонные вопросы по источникам. Метки пишем в алфавитном порядке. Если некоторый вопрос является эталонным для нескольких меток, то повторяем ссылку для каждой из них.

Преследуются сразу две цели. Во-первых, люди смогут использовать его для выявления похожих технологий. Во-вторых, его будет удобно использовать в качестве списка эталонных вопросов при необходимости закрыть вопрос про литературу как дубликат.

Помимо ссылок на чужие подборки материалов и литературы, можно создавать новые, не забыв указать метку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, метки не решают - по ним можно кучу почти одинаковых вопросов найти, причём незакрытых. Надо собрать именно эталонные и наполнить ими ответ. Шестеро же в избранное не просто так добавили вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy: про метки вы меня давно убедили, предлагаю этот аргумент включить в вопрос.

Comment: **Абсолютно все** вопросы по ссылкам на англоязычном SO были закрыты как неконструктивные или офф-топик. Формат SO (явно закрепленный в правилах) подразумевает объективные вопросы, допускающие однозначное решение. Рекомендации, длинные перечни, и прочее субьективное, не привязанное к конкретной проблеме - не входит в формат SO. Предлагаю закрыть этот вопрос.

Comment: @uhbif19 1. Они были закрыты и исключены из тематики из-за того, что стали привлекать спам. 2. На мете есть обсуждение - иди убеждать туда.

Comment: @Qwertiy Там в причине прямо сказанно "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow", то, какие к этому причины уже не важно. Окей, поищу.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Comment: нашёт тут подборку по котлин, может тоже стоит добавит в подборку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732964/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-kotlin

Comment: Очень советую этот канал на Telegram. [Книги для программистов](https://t.me/progbook) на русском и на анлийском по разным языкам программирования,администрирование, алгоритмы, проектирование, нейронные сети и т.д

Comment: Еще чуть-чуть..есть! 100 голос мой :)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

## Stack Overflow на русском

- [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474415/)
- [android](/questions/tagged/android) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692639/)
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584)
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263)
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [Где взять стандарт C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797)
- [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Fortran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1408847)
- [godot](/questions/tagged/godot) [gdscript](/questions/tagged/gdscript) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Godot и GDScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1499310)
- [golang](/questions/tagged/golang) [Книги, документация, статьи и курсы по Go](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436505)
- [html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924441/262779)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/)
- [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732964/)
- [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582544)
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/)
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125)
- [r](/questions/tagged/r) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по языку R](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506597)
- [rust](/questions/tagged/rust) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Rust](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1501087)
- [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) [Книги и учебные материалы по SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784137/213987)
- [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [nosql](/questions/tagged/nosql) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по проектированию БД: SQL && NoSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924356/262779)
- [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/)
- [алгоритмы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b) [Книги по теме "Алгоритмы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576507/)
- [безопасность](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) [Источники по безопасному (Secure) программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471356)
- [машинное-обучение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) [Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678970)
- [наука-о-данных](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) [Книги и учебные ресурсы на тему науки о данных (data science)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1539802/)
- [тестирование](/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) [Книги и другие учебные материалы по тестированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451404)

Comment: [Официально бесплатные книги на русском, большой список, множество языков и технологий.](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books-ru.md)

Comment: Не хватает ссылок на с без ++. Есть ряд вопросов по с.

Answer (score 63):

## Stack Overflow на английском

- [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)
- [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22873/10743113)
- [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js): [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js/5511507)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript): [Best resources to learn JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript) [удалённый вопрос]
- [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js): [Good books for learning D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930748/a-good-book-for-learning-d3-js/16931395#16931395)
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Кстати, есть вот такая вот статья на английском SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Comment: [Официально бесплатные книги на английском, огромный список, множество языков и технологий.](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md)

Comment: @Qwertiy битая ссылка на node.js, javascript

Comment: @AzizUmarov, node.js не битая, просто вопрос закрыли. Javascript удалён 3 года назад, но при наличии 10К репутации его можно смотреть.

Comment: @AzizUmarov https://web.archive.org/web/20160525105236/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript в архиве еще можно посмотреть вопрос