# Node.js изучение в 2015

Tags: node.js, express

Какие есть актуальные ресурсы или книги для изучения node.js и express на русском?

Comment: Предлагаю не закрывать, а сформировать ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, сейчас 1 проголосует и амба. А ответ действительно нужен, потому что тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F только на английском.

Comment: @Visman сформировать можно и после закрытия. достаточно попросить модератора переоткрыть вопрос, если ответ будет готов. А в текущем формате - максимум, накидают пару ответов со ссылками вникуда.

Comment: @Qwertiy да там на русском то всего три книги на озоне и почти никаких ресурсов, кроме руководств на различных блогах. Хотя книги могут быть неплохими: Шелли Пауэрс - "Изучаем Node.js", "Node.js. Путеводитель по технологии" и "Node.js Разработка серверных веб-приложений".

Comment: @AlexKrass, можно еще "Node.js в действии (Кантелон, Хартер, Головайчук, Райлих)" посмотреть. Но вопрос, кмк, типичный опросник.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, для таких вопросов мы как раз собираем небольшую базу [rustackoverflow: Книги и другие материалы для обучения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/Книги-и-другие-материалы-для-обучения), поэтому имеет смысл на него ответить и перенести ссылку на ответ в общие рекомендации по JS.

Comment: @AlexKrass, ага, там уже 4 голоса за закрытие висит :)

Comment: @Visman, да и пускай висят. В любом случае модераторы скорее всего закрывать не будут, слишком полезный вопрос-ответ как для пользователей, так и для предотвращения спама. К тому же на английском SO подобные вещи как раз имеют право на жизнь.

Comment: Ещё есть http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast - замечательный курс, но он несколько устарел.