# Источники по безопасному (Secure) программированию

Tags: javascript, java, c++, python, c

Какие есть ресурсы (книги, форумы, статьи) по безопасному программированию (Secure Programs).

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 8):

Безопасность в вебе:

- статьи и рекомендации от [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org)
- [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook: Finding and Exploiting Security Flaws](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118026470), Dafydd Stuttard, Marcus Pinto
- [The Tangled Web: A Guide to Securing Modern Web Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593273886), Michal Zalewski

Secure Code от Microsoft:

- [Ссылки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570401.aspx) на best practices и "how-to"-статьи по написанию secure code
- [Writing Secure Code (2nd Edition) (Developer Best Practices)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735617228), David LeBlanc, Michael Howard