# Посоветуйте самый популярный англоязычный сайт с онлайн тестами по программированию

Tags: javascript, java, sql

Посоветуйте самый популярный англоязычный  сайт с онлайн тестами (не задачами) по программированию, т.е сайт у которого большая посещаемость (например русский  самый популярный сайт quizful.net)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Источники по безопасному (Secure) программированию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471356/%d0%98%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-secure-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Всё-таки не похоже, что это вопрос дублирует указанный...

Comment: @Alex.B, а при чём тут безопасное программирование?

Comment: извините не  туда посмотрел. была тема про книги, ресурсы и про тесты тоже.

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё отличный сайт - [codewars](http://www.codewars.com/). Это архив с небольшими тренировочными задачами для программистов (называются они ката).
После того как ката выбрана и решена, можно заработать очки опыта, если написанный код проходит тесты. И после отправки ответа показываются решения других участников. Языков программирования для выбора там довольно таки немало:

- Clojure
- CoffeeScript
- C++
- C#
- Elixir
- Java
- JavaScript
- Haskell
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- TypeScript

В будущем вроде бы планируется добавить и другие языки.