# Материалы по информационной безопасности

Tags: безопасность, книги

Мне 13 лет, я хочу начать развиваться в сфере информационной безопасности  но не могу правильно начать(у меня есть некоторые знания в этой сфере но они ничтожно малы) помогите правильно начать развиваться, посоветуйте курсы, книги и т.п. пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471356/178988), но я не уверен, это дубликат или нет. Если нет, то можно было бы составить новый список.

Comment: @Qwertiy это определённо не та тема, тут вопрос по ИБ, а там же о том как защититься от эксплойтов, дыр и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

По запросу в Google "информационная безопасность" в топе выдачи - вполне себе уважаемые курсы:

- Курсы по информационной безопасности в центре «Специалист»
  https://www.specialist.ru/section/information-security
- Обучение по информационной безопасности на факультете GeekBrains
  https://geekbrains.ru/geek_university/security

Книги есть в этом ответе на Хабре:

- https://qna.habr.com/q/91243