# Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript

Tags: javascript, книги, faq, javascript-faq

Рекомендуемая литература, учебники и документация по JavaScript.

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям (когда они будут).
- Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги.
- Пожалуйста,

  - **[не добавляйте сюда видеолекции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/181472) и интерактивные курсы**,
  - не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: Вопросы SO предполагаются объективными и имеющими решение. Длинные перечни, тем более вообще без какого-то запроса, нарушают формат SO. Я предлагаю закрыть этот вопрос.

Comment: @uhbif19 **сообщество** на Мете [приняло решение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/161/181100) о разрешении подобных списков литературы, как канонических вопросов по теме, под меткой [tag:книги]. Посему, закрытия не будет. Но подобные вопросы **не**канонического характера будут закрываться. Если получится, как дубликаты. Такие перечни нужно поддерживать, поэтому какие получится собрать -- зависит от состава сообщества.

Comment: @D-side Вы пытаетесь создать энциклопедию из сайта вопросов и ответов. Всё равно что забивать гвозди микроскопом. Мою правку ответа например просто удалили, хотя моё дополнение ничуть не хуже. Теряется всякая логика stackoverflow. Этот вопрос, хотя это вообще не вопрос, а статья, нужно удалить т.к. он не является вопросом, а является статьёй.

Comment: @Khipster Книги - да, видеокурсы - нет. А вашу правку я откатил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Прочитай свою же писанину: "Рекомендуемая литература, документация и курсы по JavaScript". Курсы, Карл!

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вы ломаете всякую логику работы stackoverflow, создавая статьи вместо вопросов, а вместо ответов используя один мега-ответ. Это забивание гвоздей микроскопом. Криворукость в чистом виде.

Comment: @Khipster может и так, но сообщество с вами не согласно. Вопрос о том, стоит ли добавлять туда видеокурсы, можете вынести на Мету.

Comment: @D-side Сообщество не согласно не со мной, а с правилами: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Khipster консенсус на Мете выше правил. Как законы и референдум, это "волеизъявление населения". Правила описывают общие принципы, Мета -- краевые случаи.

Comment: @D-side Это полная анархия, а никакие не правила. А что до консенсуса на Мете так это вообще нисколько не объективное решение.

Comment: @Khipster да, не объективное, но это решение большинства активных участников. Разрешение на отдельные исключения из правил в уверенности, что пользы от них будет больше, чем вреда.

Comment: @Khipster абзац из [справки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), на который вы ссылаетесь, дописывал туда лично я. И там нет ни слова про видеокурсы, только о книгах речь. В данном вопросе под курсами понимаются учебники, а не видео.

Comment: @Khipster http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/181472

Answer (score 80, accepted):

## JavaScript

1. [Douglas Crockford — «JavaScript: The Good Parts», 2008](http://javascript.crockford.com/)
   (Не рекомендуется новичкам в JS)
2. [Marijn Haverbeke — «Eloquent JavaScript: A Modern Introduction to Programming», 2014](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)
3. [Addy Osmani — «Learning JavaScript Design Patterns», 2012](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)
   (Не рекомендуется новичкам в программировании)
4. Стоян Стефанов — «JavaScript. Шаблоны», 2011
5. Дэвид Флэнаган — «JavaScript. Подробное руководство», 2012
   (Допустим для новичков в программировании, но ориентирован не на них)
6. Дэвид Херман — «Сила JavaScript. 68 способов эффективного использования JS», 2013
7. Эрик Фримен, Элизабет Робсон — «Изучаем программирование на JavaScript», 2015
   (Подойдет для начинающих)
8. Джон Резиг, Беэр Бибо — «Секреты JavaScript ниндзя», 2015
   (Подойдет для более продвинутых)
9. Джон Резиг, Расс Фергюсон, Джон Пакстон — «JavaScript для профессионалов», 2017 (Подойдет для более продвинутых)
10. [Илья Кантор — «Современный учебник Javascript»](http://learn.javascript.ru/) 
    (В основном ориентирован на работу online, но есть и pdf/epub версия. Достаточно дружелюбен для новичков)
11. Mozilla Developer Network — [раздел о JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript)
    (Хороший онлайн справочник по языку, но есть и учебник)
12. Metanit.com - [Web разработка / JavaScript](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/) (Такой же хороший онлайн справочник, что и Mozilla Developer Network)
13. [Cпецификация](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (формальное описание синтаксиса, базовых объектов и алгоритмов) языка Javascript - называется ECMAScript.
14. Николас Закас - JavaScript для профессиональных веб-разработчиков (3-е изд.) - 2015. 960 стр. Несмотря на название - для новичков самое-то. Шикарная книга.
15. Николас Закас - ECMAScript 6 для разработчиков - 2017. Книга расскажет о всех изменениях в JS, внесенных ECMAScript 6. (не для
    новичков).
16. Мэтт Фрисби - JavaScript для профессиональных веб-разработчиков, 2022
17. Кайл Симпсон - "Серия" Вы не знаете JS в шести книгах, 2013-2015
18. Стоян Стефанов - «JavaScript. Шаблоны», 2011
19. Дуглас Крокфорд - «Как устроен JavaScript», 2019
20. Луис Атенсио - «Функциональное программирование на JavaScript», 2020
21. Мартин Фаулер - «Рефакторинг кода на JavaScript», 2019
22. Stoyan Stefanov - «Object-Oriented JavaScript», 2017
23. Николас Закас - «JavaScript. Оптимизация производительности», 2012
24. Хантер Томас II, Инглиш Брайан - «Многопоточный JavaScript», 2022
25. Кирупа Чиннатхамби - «JavaScript с нуля», 2021
26. [Doka - удобный справочник по JavaScript](https://doka.guide/js/)

## jQuery

1. Бер Бибо, Иегуда Кац — «jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript», 2011

Comment: В этом списке не хватает книги Николаса Закаса "javascript для профессиональных веб-разработчиков"

Comment: @Дмытрык так добавьте )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Может стоит сюда добавит ещё и какие-нибудь учебники по TypeScript? (у меня, к сожалению, нет рекомендаций, я как раз в надежде их тут найти сюда пришёл :D)

Comment: @MrModest охотно бы, но у меня тоже нет рекомендаций.

Comment: А чо все книги такие старые? ))) Ну кроме 2017. Рекомендую Илью Кантора - он так и пишет - вот вам информация для понимания, но это старое говно и не надо его использовать.