# Как понять JavaScript в общем

Tags: javascript

Изучил HTML5, CSS3, сейчас хочу спросить знающих: куда двигаться?

Как понять JavaScript? Сейчас я практикуюсь с товарищем,он преподаёт и параллельно мне даёт программу.

Хотел бы спросить для эффективного изучения этого языка что нужно? Может какие-то крутые книги, ресурсы? Может быть есть какой-то,скажем,механизм для более лучшего и глубокого восприятия? Меня очень привлекает разработка. Я хочу изучить всё. Всю структуру, библиотеки, шаблонизаторы и т.д.

Может быть можно попасть в какой-нибудь open-source проект, где можно набраться опыта и т.д.?

Comment: Список книг по JS [есть на сайте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/10105). Читайте, пишите код, потратьте на это года два. После этого начнёт получаться.

Comment: _"для эффективного изучения этого языка что нужно?"_ -- так же как и для изучения любого другого языка нужна практика. смотрите примеры, разбирайтесь как они работают, пробуйте переделать/добавить и т.д. читайте статьи.

Comment: Вы определили себе цель. Не лишним будет так же определить критерии оценки достигнутых результатов. Исходя из этого можно наметить промежуточные этапы на пути к достижению цели. (разобраться в том-то, освоить это и т.п.) А далее уже поиск инструментов и ресурсов для достижения очередного этапа. 
И да, серебряной пули не существует. Универсального метода изучения чего-либо нет. Тут вам нужно ориентироваться исключительно на себя и трезво оценивать свои силы и текущие возможности (дабы не начать то, что объективно не сможете закончить)

Answer (score 1):

Например:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm - справочник на англ.

https://learn.javascript.ru/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/37619/ - здесь этот же вопрос обговаривали

http://www.itmathrepetitor.ru/zadachi-po-javascript-iz-knigi-vyrazitelnyjj-javascript/

http://codepen.io/ https://jsfiddle.net/ - онлайн редакторы