# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, книги, faq, unity3d-faq

Собираем подборку литературы и документации по Unity3D.

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте общий ответ.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям (при надобности добавить новый).
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент, вроде торрент-трекеров.
- **Единственная ссылка на видео** будет на обучающие материалы с **[Официального сайта Unity3D](https://unity3d.com)**. Остальные видеолекции и интерактивные курсы **добавлять запрещено!**

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

В первую очередь надо изучить либо [C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) и поэтому [ссылка на литературу по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/), либо [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) и [ссылка на литературу по Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/).

---

## Скриптинг:

- Joseph Hocking — Unity in Action. Multiplatform game development in C# with Unity 5, 2015

  *Русский перевод*: Джозеф Хокинг — Unity в действии. Мультиплатформенная разработка на C#, 2016
- Alan Thorn — Mastering Unity Scripting, 2015

  *Русский перевод*: Алан Торн — Искусство создания сценариев в Unity, 2016

---

## Шейдеры:

- Kenny Lammers — Unity Shaders and Effects Cookbook, 2013

  *Русский перевод*: Кенни Ламмерс — Шейдеры и эффекты в Unity, 2014
- Alan Zucconi, Kenneth Lammers — Unity 5.x Shaders and Effects Cookbook, 2016

---

## Мультиплеер:

- Alan R. Stagner — Unity Multiplayer Games, 2013

---

## Анимация:

- Alan Thorn — Unity Animation Essentials, 2015

  *Русский перевод*: Алан Торн — Основы анимации в Unity, 2016

---

## Дополнительно:

- Alan Thorn — How to Cheat in Unity 5: Tips and Tricks for Game Development, 2015
- Chris Dickinson — Unity 5 Game Optimization, 2015

---

## Видео уроки (только официальные):

- [Обучающие материалы — Главная страница с разделами](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials)
- [Обучающие материалы — Скриптинг](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting)

---

## P.S.

<sub>(updated by @АлексейШиманский)</sub>

Следующий список представленных книг прочитаны и оценены программистами, купившие книгу на Amazon. На сколько оценка соответствует проф. статусу — сказать я не могу, но утаивать данный список книг я считаю неправильным и преступным)). Каждый здесь сможет почерпнуть для себя что-то дельное и необходимое.

Справа от названия будет оценка книги по 5-ти бальной шкале. Пример: 4/5.

```css
.left {
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 0px
}

.left,
.right {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan Thorn — How to Cheat in Unity 5 Tips and tricks</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan Thorn — Mastering Unity Scripting</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Joseph Hocking — Unity in Action (Джозеф Хокинг — Unity в действии)</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Кенни Ламмерс — Шейдеры и эффекты в Unity</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan R. Stagner — Unity Multiplayer Games</span>
  <span class="right">3.4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan Zucconi, Kenneth Lammers — Unity 5.x Shaders and Effects Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Chris Dickinson — Unity 5 Game Optimization</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Jeremy Gibson — Introduction to Game Design, Prototyping, and Development</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Matt Smith — Unity 5.x Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Ryan Henson Creighton — Unity 3D Game Development</span>
  <span class="right">3.9/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Sue Blackman — Beginning 3D Game Development with Unity</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Terry Norton — Learning C# by Developing Games with Unity 3D (Veeeeeeeeerrry Beginner's Guide)</span>
  <span class="right">3.7/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Venita Pereira — Learning Unity 2D Game Development by Example</span>
  <span class="right">3/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Simon Jackson — Mastering Unity 2D Game Development</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Dave Calabrese — Unity 2D Game Development</span>
  <span class="right">2.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Edward Lavieri — Getting Started with Unity 5</span>
  <span class="right">2.9/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">John P. Doran — Building an FPS Game with Unity</span>
  <span class="right">4.2/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Jonathan Linowes — Unity Virtual Reality Projects</span>
  <span class="right">4.2/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Valera Cogut — Unity 5 for Android Essentials</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Jonathan Linowes — Unity Virtual Reality Projects</span>
  <span class="right">4.2/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Jorge Palacios — Unity 5.x Game AI Programming Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">3.3/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Maciej Szczesnik — Unity 5.x Animation Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">4.4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Patrick Felicia — Unity 5 From Zero to Proficiency</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">K. Aava Rani — Learning Unity Physics</span>
  <span class="right">3.3/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Ryan Watkins — Procedural Content Generation for Unity Game Development</span>
  <span class="right">3.8/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Francesco Sapio Abdelrahman Saher — Unity 5.x 2D Game Development Blueprints</span>
  <span class="right">???</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Francesco Sapio — Unity UI Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">4.3/5</span>
</div>
```