# Почему не удается использовать код?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Начал учится работать в Unity3D по обучающему видео и в нем был код (который не заработал):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    rigidbody.velocity.y = 8;
```

Полазив по интернету и попробовав несколько вариантов у меня все заработало, только когда я заменил код на такой:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 8, 0);
```

Почему вместо этого не работает первый вариант, или вариант:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    rb.velocity.y = 8;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что время бежит, всё меняется. И если раньше в старых версиях программного продукта можно было писать одни конструкции, то в поздних версиях что-то меняется на другие.

Так, к примеру `rigidbody.velocity` (а еще audio, renderer, collider и многое другое) можно было писать в *Unity* версии № 4. С 5 версии все происходит через вызов нужных компонентов через `GetComponent<SOME_COMPONENT>();` в *C#* и `GetComponent(SOME_COMPONENT);` в *JS*

Аналогично с `velocity.y`. Возможно раньше можно было так писать, однако сейчас присваивание направления или скорости или все, что связанно с *Vector3* (и не только вектор) происходит цельно, т.е. через вызов `new Vector3(0, 8, 0)`

Comment: А есть ли какая нибудь  добротная литература по новым стандартам Unity или программированию на движке в целом?

Comment: @Enwinkel ну вообще всё что нового в продукте обычно  пишется прямо в выпуске на оф. сайте...... вот например https://unity3d.com/ru/unity/whats-new/unity-5.0 ... там можно найти кстати пункт `Removed quick property accessors...` как раз про доступ через `GetComponent`... так что кмк это единственная литература по новым фишкам............а литературу в общем пока могу только вот это показать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609901/191482  ......ну и этот список пошерстить: https://gcup.ru/forum/8-46855-1  .

Comment: @Enwinkel самое смешное, что я буквально час назад вынул винт на диагностику (и не знаю теперь когда подключу), в котором список книг нарисован на прочитку :D    хз правда их адекватность. надо изучать

Comment: да порядок, думаю мне списка на стекОверфлоу что ты скинул пока с головой хватит =)

Comment: @Enwinkel добавил в раздел книги по юнити еще список из 20 штук 
   ...... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609901/191482 ..... и описание к списку. Думаю будет полезно в будущем