# Передача состояния анимаций из одного класса в другой

Tags: c#, unity3d

В одном классе при конкретном действии проигрывается анимация атаки, а в другом классе проверяется столкновение 2-х коллайдеров. Когда они столкнулись, то у противника минусую жизнь. Проблема в том, что даже если не атаковал, а только столкнулся, то всё равно минусуется жизнь.

Как передать статус анимаций в другой класс, чтобы только при атаке работало?

Comment: Что за игра такая? файтинг? 2D или 3D? можно скрин?

Comment: Сделать в классе ссылку на противника. Когда они столкнулись записывать противника, а когда разошлись обнулять. Ну и отнимать жизнь через некое время

Comment: @ValeraKvip я подозреваю товарищ не может отличить когда они столкнулись, а когда просто сошлись. (причем я не уверен что там они сталкиваются вообще). Отсюда, вроде, и вопрос. ...и отсюда мой вопрошающий-уточняющий коммент тоже))

Comment: Игра  3д, про космос персонаж на луне

Comment: А тогда причём тут атака и столкновения? ведь сталкиваются корабли, а атакуют лазером или пулями и т.д.

Comment: Атака бывает 2 видов Range  и Mele. 
В моей игре Mele, персонаж должен ударить противника что бы отнять жизнь 
Но! есть я не нажимаю кнопку атаки а убегаю и задеваю противника то ему всё равно отнимает жизнь потому что противник вошёл в триггер.
Мне нужно проверить если была проиграна анимация атаки и противник вошёл в триггер то только в этом случае отнять жизнь, как мне проверить если была проиграна анимация ? и как мне передать статус анимаций в другой класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое: при любом виде ближней атаки заноси значение в переменную, например `isMeleeAttack`, после окончания атаки - снимай значение.

Собственно, при вхождении в триггер проверяй значение этой переменной — если не null, значит сейчас идет атака, а значит надо произвести вычет жизней.

Саму анимацию можно разными путями отслеживать... Например если это `Mecanim`, то

```
if (this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("YourAnimationName"))
{
    // значит происходит удар....
}
```

Проверить на вхождение хотя бы одной играющей анимации придется в цикле....

---

Если же анимация через `Animation`, то проверить можно через
[Animation.isPlaying](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation-isPlaying.html)

Comment: Пожалуйста скажите как передать значение анимаций в другой класс

Comment: @Abs3akt так в событии уже всё будет. `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` вот в этом `other.gameObject` лежит как раз тот самый объект, который вошёл в триггер, тобишь тот, кто ударил. То есть `other.gameObject.isMeleeAttack` и будет

Comment: @Abs3akt вообще зачем вам значение анимации в другом классе и какие именно значения хотите получить?

Comment: Смотрите есть триггер на player (GTAttack), есть противник Zombi когда я бегу от зомби,Врезался в него Но не атакую его Триггер всё равно срабатывает! 
Метод для урона наносяшего Player-ом находится в файле Zombi поэтому мне нужно при входе Playera в триггер проверить сработала ли анимация атаки Playera. просмотрите пожалуйста последний мой коментарий чуть выше который спрятан я там обьяснял. 
P.S  прошу прошение за мою орфографию ( самоучка русского языка)

Comment: кто то говорил про делегаты что они используются для передачи из одного класса в другой, но я не знаю точно 
Но всё равно вам большое спасибо за помошь

Comment: @Abs3akt Так я написал в ответе что нужно делать. В самом классе Player следишь за анимацией и выставляешь флаг, что играет анимация атаки или нет.... А при входе в триггер проверяешь этот флаг......то есть зомби будет считывать только его....об анимации ему знать не обязательно

Comment: @Abs3akt делегаты..может быть...вообще есть GetComponent (чтоб найти компонент и взять у него что-то), есть SendMessage И BroadcastMessage для посылки сообщений, есть Events (ивенты активно используются)..... можешь что-то попробовать почерпнуть из [книг](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609901/191482)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за сылку на книги!
вопрос решил Большое спасибо! 
Вот как решил вопрос.
`public Animator PlayerAnimator;
private float timerDamageGoat = 0.5f;
private bool isAttackEnable = true;`

`void OnTriggerStay (Collider target)
 {
  if (target.tag == "GTdamage") {           
   if (isAttackEnable && goatAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName("flyAttack")) {
    isAttackEnable = false;
     Goatdamage = Random.Range (15, 18);
     hpStatusZom = hpStatusZom - Goatdamage;
    if (hpStatusZom <= 0) {
     deadZombie ();
     zombieIsReload = true;
  }}
  }
 }`

Comment: @Abs3akt как я описал в ответе: т.к. анимаций атак может много, то скорее желательно сделать функцию (например `bool IsAnimationPlaying`), в которой в цикле проверятся все эти анимации. и чтоб каждый раз не писать большие конструкции......................P.S. есть  у меня большой список книг, но я стремаюсь пока в тот раздел их выкладывать....не проверены