# Разработка игр, изучение 2D/3D графики?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, graphics

Добрый день коллеги.

Я разработчик в гос.конторе ("плюсы" + MFC), хочу перейти на Unity+C#. Проблема только в том, что я не знаком с компьютерной графикой (с математикой всё в порядке) и, прежде чем преступить к Unity, я хочу изучить саму графику, ибо раньше я не знал о таких вещах как: полигон, меши; чем отличается растровая от векторной графики.

Поэтому прошу вас, коллеги, укажите мне нормальный ресурс (книга, видео), где хорошо и полностью описывается компьютерная графика от и до. Хотя бы в том объёме, который нужен для разработки игр.

Всё, что я находил в сети дало мне очень обрывочные понятия.

**P.S.** Хочу сказать, что это не дубликат вопроса [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/191482), т.к. там книги по юнити непосредственно. Указание Unity+C# добавлено для того, чтобы было понятнее для чего мне нужна графика.

Comment: Видеокурсы ищи. Разные. На торрент трекерах они есть. Дальше ничего лучше обрывков статей и краткой документации не будет.
 Тебе нужно занать конкретно Юнити а не графику. Графика это слишком широко. Если хорошо знаешь C++ то почему Юнити а не Unreal Engine?

Comment: @codename0082016
 - Unity очень хорошь для разработки под смартфоны и C# как-то по приятней ...

Comment: Неужели шарп вам нравится больше чем плюсы?

Comment: Большинство смартов работают под андроид, если не ошибаюсь, там вроде java рулит?

Comment: @nick_n_a, да это правда, как по мне это очень хороший ЯП

Comment: @nick_n_a, На Шарпе можно писать под все устройства используя Unity или Xamarin

Comment: @nick_n_a не рулит. В области игр популярнее нативные языки.

Comment: @Grundy вряд ли дубль... там нет книг про графику....это, кмк, вообще не к Unity вопрос, а к какому-нибудь 3dSMax или Maya, Blender .... особенно `чем отличается растровая от векторной графики.`

Comment: Тогда вопрос должен отражать именно то что спрашивается. Вверху написано: хочу с# + unity, а потом "я хочу изучить саму графику". Может лучше тогда спросить какие графические 2D/3D библиотеки бывают для c#?

Comment: Автор, считай как хочешь, но игры на C++ куда перспективнее чем Unity. Например а Acrivision не хватает хороших C++ разработчиков (смекаешь к чему я?). Да и в Ubisoft тоже.

Comment: @nick_n_a - Вам что друзья делать нечего или вы возомнили себя богами здесь ? Вопрос задан чётко и корректно, указание Unity+C# добавлено для того что бы было понятнее для чего мне нужна графика ... Ну как в детский сад попал честное слово ! Если нечего сказать по теме проходите мимо ...

Comment: Делать игры на ПЕКА (царский) или на мыльную соснольку куда перспективнее чем клепать их на все подряд.

Comment: @EugenEray причем тут игры на каком-то ЯП и графика? .... В юнити есть такая штука как IL2CPP. Смекаешь к чему я?

Comment: @Eugen Eray - Спасибо добрый человек, может это и верно, но сперва хотел разобраться с самой графикой ...

Comment: @Alter_DRON Знаешь, в случае если ты не собираешься делать сам текстурки, то тебе не надо учить графику - ты можешь найти вполне годные модельки в Assets Store.

Comment: Пожалуй, каждый отдельный вопрос нужно писать с абзаца, и давать ему номер. А так это чисто психология - люди начало прочитали - поняли ответили, а до концовки вопроса прониклись не все.

Comment: @nick_n_a Тут похоже скоро гора комментов будет :0

Comment: @EugenEray уточнение: С++ в ходу в больших командах, и творческой свободы в таких минимум (для тех, кто её ищет, конечно). Небольшие команды готовы мириться даже с такими страшными языками, как GML, если процесс разработки и получения обратной связи при этом хорошо поставлен (а коммерческие IDE обычно в этом преуспевают).

Comment: Я б сейчас отозвал голос за дубликат (который казался на тот момент оправданным), но вопрос всё равно подлежит закрытию, как слишком общий -- "голый минимум" знаний по графике для разработки игр **отсутствует**, ибо быстро постигается из документации к движку. А максимум (который "хорошо и полностью") о-о-о-очень далеко и включает в себя килотонны материала (посмотрите на размеры книг GPU Gems, например).

Comment: Что бы понять как работает 3D графика попробуй ее поделать. Помодель немного в blender - так ты поймешь что откуда берется и как работает, при этом нет нужны в глубоком его изучении, просто для развития. А изучая юнити термины сами подтянуться. И у юнити есть офф уроки, так что обучаясь юнити  и решая конкретные задачи ты разберешься и в графике.По поводу коментов выше, то выбор верный! Я использовал и плюсы и шарп. Лично для меня плюсы это язык для создания багов, и исправления багов его создателей.  А в шарпе у меня не бывает багов, только там где я сам накосячил.

Comment: @Valera Kvip - благодарю тебя коллега за достойный и информативный ответ ! Последую твоим рекомендациям ...