# Unity 2d повернуть спрайт из меню Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d, спрайт, rotation

Есть спрайт, то на разных локациях он должен быть повернут по разному. Поворачивать нужно не со скрипта. 
В rigidbody2d нашел вкладку Info с элементом rotation, но секция заморожена. 
Пробовал искать в сети, пробовал менять разные настройки rigidbody2d, но ничего не удалось.

Как крутить спрайт с меню?

Comment: как и все объекты - через transform - rotation  https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/InspectorRotationEulerAngles.png

Comment: хех, спасибо огромное) 
Только начал работать с Unity)

Comment: так может хотя бы в начале в доки заглянуть и в [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/191482) ?