# Как мне правильно начать изучать unity и C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня нет опыта программирования, не знаю как лучше начать изучать C#, с Unity уже немного знаком, поскольку купил несколько курсов. Я хочу начать с 2D игр на android. Создавать думаю что-то вроде time-киллеров, а потом после того как наберусь опыта уже что-то более серьезное.
Я не знаю как мне лучше начать изучать C#, какие книги покупать?, какие курсы смотреть?, Как вообще получить базу знаний о C#, чтобы открыть VScode и начать печатать скрипт

Comment: @And и даже еще вот это: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/199253)

Comment: @СергейМишин, Это уже после того, как будет знать язык.

Comment: @And поэтому написано "еще", а не "скорее"))

Comment: Начать пренепременно стоит с **основ C#**