# Unity c# профессия изучение

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет,я хочу стать unity разработчиком ,меня интересует есть ли те кто мог бы ответить мне на нескольок вопросов 
С чего вы начали,по каким источникам изучали,какие минимальные знания нужны для того чтобы устраиваться на работу 
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Начинать конечно с книг. [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/199253), минимальные знания: база языка C# или javascript (для юнити рекомендую всё же C#), база по Unity из книг про скриптинг (ссылка выше). Для того, чтобы устроиться на работу - не угадаешь. Могут на ученика взять и совсем без знаний. Поэтому я рекомендую: C# база, включая знания фич до .NET 4.6, книги по юнити из списка выше, написать наобум любую игрушку, хоть тетрис, чтоб просто поковырять и ориентироваться примерно и атаковать ВСЕХ работодателей и умолять взять учеником

Comment: Хотите игроделаньем заняться, сударушка?) К сожалению не могу ответить конкретно на Ваш вопрос, но в общих чертах ответ примерно таков: найдите себе стажировку. Учёба учёбой, но без хорошего наставника и практики толку от неё немного. Люди склонны зацикливаться и им сложно учить что-то новое, решать более сложные, нетипичные задачи. Стажировка позволит получать знания быстрее, ещё и зарабатывать вдобавок

Comment: YouTube полон курсов C# Unity c нуля. Для трудоустройства нужно быть программистов C# и знать базовым набором паттернов и алгаритмов, точнее можно погуглить о вопросах на собеседовании `junior` программиста C#.

Comment: Для ознакомительных целей для начала можно пройти коротенький курс https://learn.unity.com/project/beginner-gameplay-scripting

Comment: @СергейМишин Unity уже не поддерживает JS.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ну слааава богу наконец-то :D

Comment: @СергейМишин да и на самом деле никто особо и не пользовался, поэтому они его и убрали :)

Comment: Не получатся ответить на комментарии, поэтому спасибо всем большое  за ответы и советы, за предоставление материала ,я вам очень благодарна))