# Проблема в вызове компонентов в Unity2D

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Я недавно начал изучать такой движок как Unity и у меня сразу же обнаружилась проблема.
Для своего персонажа я создал , к примеру , компонент RigiDBody2D. Далее я создаю скрипт , где хочу вызвать этот компонент , но не могу , так как он просто не появляется в списках. Не могли ли бы вы мне подсказать в чем дело? Может у меня скрипт не связан? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самый оптимальный вариант в текущей ситуации: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/199253)

Comment: И чем мне поможет ваш комментарий ? Вы думаете я не смотрел? Уж лучше бы вы просто пропустили этот пост и ничего не писали.

Comment: "Вы думаете я не смотрел?" -- Да, я уверен на все 100%, что вы не смотрели. Потому что это основы, а основы в книгах описаны. Соответственно вы начали заниматься банально не прочитав ничего по языку и движку