# Создание изометрической игры в Юнити

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Порекомендуйте пожалуйста, бесплатные хорошие видео или курс видео по созданию изометрической игры на Юнити на русском языке. Я пытался найти, но нашел только по-английски. В целом, английский я знаю не плохо, но на слух понять не могу, а субтитры не всегда хорошие.

Понимаю, что StackOverflow, наверное, не очень хорошее место для подобных вопросов. Но здесь очень быстро отвечают, поэтому планирую быстро получить ответ и закрыть вопрос.

P.S. Многие писали "Читай книги, на Ютубе не научишься", так что если вы знаете книгу или что-либо еще, напишите, буду рад прочитать.

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, не беспокойтесь)

Comment: Арман, уже третий раз пересекаемся) Знаете что-то хорошее по вопросу?

Comment: Ну я часто отвечаю на вопросы связанные с Unity.) Если бы знал, написал бы ответ. Вывод - нет.

Comment: Хотя знаю одного отличного русского [ютубера](https://www.youtube.com/user/HuaweiSonicHelp), но он объясняет в основном принцип программирования на Unity.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я просто делал игру и по ходу искал инфу и ещё помогла книжка "Юнити в действии".