# С чего начать разработку игры в unity \ ue4?

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Создавал 2д платформер на SFML&C++, так же создавал карточную игру на Android(Java+LibGDX). На С# создавал программы для работы с БД.
Вопрос следующий. Во-первых, что мне выбрать? ue4\unity?
Во-вторых. С чего начать обучение? Конечная цель создать игру.

Какую-нибуть литературу, видео-курсы и т.д

Comment: На ютьюбе полно таториалов как "от печки", так и продвинутых по Unity. На сайте Unity есть учебные проекты, которые можно покрутить по-всякому. И обучающий раздел там тоже вроде есть. UE я не пробовал просто. Насколько я понимаю, Unity на C#, а UE на C++, можно на этой основе выбирать - какой язык ближе.

Comment: Откуда возник такой вопрос если уже освоены С++ java и c#? Или то была копипаста по ютуб туториалам?

Comment: Хочу в будущем работать в gamedev и знаю, что много вакансий именно на эти позиции(Unity, UE4), по этому хочу иметь какой-нибуть опыт в этом. Ну и дополнительно это будет мой дипломный проект.

Comment: А предыдущие проекты были авторскими, никакой копипасты.

Comment: Человек, который освоил С++ java и c# не будет задавать вопросы в стиле "Где искать инфу по unity \ ue4"

Comment: Вот он я. И да, я же не сказал, что идеально знаю с++, java, c#. Я написал, что я работал с ними и создавал проекты.

Comment: Я не хочу смотреть очередной курс на ютубе в стиле "создайте игру, за которую вы получите 1млн долларов за 10 часов на unity". Я хочу максимально подробный(если такой есть) курс или книгу.

Comment: @ArchDemon на самом деле изучение игрового движка достаточно сильно отличается от изучения лишнего языка программирования. У меня при первом столкновении с Unity вообще не было практически идей в какую сторону копать.

Comment: @yolosora, для начала копать в сторону C#. Как только освоитесь с языком, то можно уже искать профильную информацию по Unity. Иначе ваша разработка игр рискует стать копи-пастой кода с туториалов без понимания происходящего. А это довольно печально

Comment: @ArchDemon это все понятно. Я как раз о том, что знание языков далеко не гарантирует отсутствие проблем даже в самом базовом освоении игрового движка как инструмента. Это что-то из серии "у человека знающего физику и черчение не будут возникать вопросы в стиле где искать инфу по архитектуре зданий"

Comment: @yolosora, для человека, который освоил столько языков самостоятельно, не должно возникать вопросов, где найти информацию про игровые движки. Ибо информацию по ЯП он где-то нашёл. Логично, что информацию по игровым движкам можно найти там же.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбора по сути нет. Если это мобильное приложение, вся монитизация заточина под `Unity`. Мобильные издательства, в редких случаях работают с проектами на других движках, а некоторые вообще не работают. Если это action игра на `PC` или консоли, то сборщик мусора `Unity`, это гробовой камень, шутер *Resident Evil Umbrella Corps* печальный пример, там не бывает стабильного fps, какое бы железо у тебя не было, при том, что там скромная графика, и лучше всё таки `Unreal`.

Литература по моему бесмысленна. Достаточно много материалов для изучения предоставляют сами разработчики движков, по всем темам и бесчисленное количество Example проектов для примеров, как от разработчиков, как и от людей. Для обоих движков самые большие комьюнити. Поскольку движки самые популярные у них не плохие документации. Ну и доки у майкросовт по языку `C#` (это их продукт) самые лучшие, на всех языках, для `C++` у них тоже есть, наверняка тоже крутые.