# Как изучать unity3d? (сам движок)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема следующая: я неплохо знаком с C++, и недавно решил попробовать свои силы в C#/Unity3d. Проблем с шарпом не возникло, случился затык с самим движком. Дело в том, что вся литература/курсы/статьи, в общем любые источники по данному вопросу, устроены по типу "вот вам пара небольших примеров", "тыкайте сюда, пишите такой код".

Пройдя таким образом несколько учебников, я пришел к выводу, что я ничему не научился. Повторить за автором могу, а вот самостоятельно прийти к аналогичному решению - нет. Не хватает какого-то источника с фундаментальной информацией по движку, такого, чтобы после прочтения я мог реализовать большинство из пришедших мне в голову механик. Ну или хотя бы чтобы я просто начал понимать как в принципе устроен unity, а дальше уже двигался методом проб и ошибок.

В связи с этим вопрос к тем, кто сейчас на пути в геймдев, либо же уже является опытным разработчиком.

Как вы осваивали движок? Какую литературу порекомендуете? Может быть unity в принципе не нуждается в подобном фундаментальном руководстве? Но тогда какой подход должен быть при изучении?

Ваш опыт был бы очень полезен для меня.

Правка:

Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D мне и так известны в огромном количестве.
Меня интересуют фундаментальные знания, а не то, о чем я писал выше.

Пожалуйста, читайте внимательно вопрос.

Продублирую его: "Как вы осваивали unity3d?".

Подчеркну, что вопрос адресован узкому кругу людей... И если вы к нему не относитесь, пожалуйста, проигнорируйте его. Не тратьте ни свое, ни чужое время.

Спасибо.

Правка №2 (специально для Yaroslav):

Обращаемся к правке №1. Третья строчка все объясняет.

Comment: while(true) Видос на ютубе -> Документация -> Реализация

Comment: То есть вам того количество гайдов и видео в интеренетах мало, и вам нужен еще один персональный? Ваш вопрос больше похож на страх перед проблемой. Ответ прост: начните писать код.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Comment: @aepot Нет, то количество "гайдов и видео в интернетах" мне не мало, и мне не нужен персональный. Мне нужен нормальный источник информации. Попробуйте освоить математику по книге в которой решены 10 примеров и к ним даны комментарии в духе "я сделал вот так, потому что вот".

Answer (score 2):

Исходи из того что тебе нужно реализовать. Например делаешь проект шутера в учебных целях. Сначала гуглишь как создать модель оружия, потом как вставить ее в проект, потом как реализовать стрельбу и т.д. Методом проб и ошибок наберешься опыта.

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что исчерпывающего руководства по движку не существует? Неужели все таким образом учатся?

Comment: @dexx существует документация на английском, и в принципе тем, кто более-менее знает C#, её достаточно.

Comment: @aepot О, спасибо большое. Надеюсь, что документации действительно хватит.

Comment: @dexx На сайте самого Unity 3D смотрели? Там и доки, и видео, и проекты учебные есть.