# Пожалуйста, посоветуйте годные книги по программированию на C# под Unity или просто про скриптинг

Tags: c#, unity3d, книги

Пожалуйста, посоветуйте годные книги по программированию на C# под Unity, можно и не C#. Главное чтобы было про скриптинг в плане игровой индустрии.
В данный момент я новичок только пробую себя в сфере геймдев.
Решил начать с Unity. И когда впервый раз зашёл в Движок. Сразу задался кучей вопросов по скриптингу. (Интерфейс я быстро разобрал).
Ну вообщем, суть моей проблемы стала вам известна. Надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: @0xdb  ребят ну не книги по C#, а книги по Unity . Написано же русским по белому))

Comment: @tym32167 ребят ну не книги по C#, а книги по Unity . Написано же русским по белому))

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/191482)