# Смена значения fillAmount

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в скрипте сделать, чтобы после начала использования void StartSlow значение в fillAmount шло к 0, а после void StopSlow значение обратно шло к 1?

Вот сам скрипт

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SlowDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image SlowValue;
    //private float TValue1 = -0.01f;
    //private float TValue2 = +0.01f;

    private void Start()
    {
        SlowValue = GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    // Активация функции Void
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            StartSlow();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            StopSlow();
        }

        if (SlowValue.fillAmount == 0.01f)
            StopSlow();

        
    }
    void StartSlow()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0.4f;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;

    }

    void StopSlow()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;

    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поверь, товарищ, с момента твоего прошлого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1344144/191482  ничего не поменялось. Советы всё те же.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В книге "Unity в действии" в какой главе мой вопрос?

Comment: Ты ожидаешь, что в программировании не нужно думать головой, а только копипастить код из книг и интернета? Ошибаешься.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ты гений, правда. Может я хочу посмотреть как это работает и как с этим работать? С чего ты взял, что я тупо скопирую из книги код и забью?

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть как это работает, люди обычно думают логически и приходят у умозаключениям. На основе них пишут код на языке, который **предварительно изучили**. Три вопроса: 1) Ты изучил ЯП? 2) Ты логически рассуждал над данной задачей? 3) К чему пришёл в ходе рассуждений?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;


public class StackOverflow : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _fillAmount;
    private float _changingSpeed = 1f;
    private float _accuracy = 0.01f;
    private Coroutine _changeFillAmountCoroutine;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            StartSlow();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            StopSlow();
        }
    }

    private void StartSlow()
    {
        // если fillAmount уже меняется, приостанавливаем этот процесс
        if (_changeFillAmountCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_changeFillAmountCoroutine);
        }
        
        // устремляем fillAmount к 0
        _changeFillAmountCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ChangeFillAmount(0));
    }

    private void StopSlow()
    {
        // если fillAmount уже меняется, приостанавливаем этот процесс
        if (_changeFillAmountCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_changeFillAmountCoroutine);
        }
        
        // устремляем fillAmount к 1
        _changeFillAmountCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ChangeFillAmount(1));
    }
    
    private IEnumerator ChangeFillAmount(float target)
    {
        var waitForEndOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        while (Math.Abs(_fillAmount - target) >= _accuracy)
        {
            // меняем fillAmount. _changingSpeed отвечает за то,
            // как быстро вы хотите, чтобы fillAmount стремился к своему целевому значению
            _fillAmount = Mathf.MoveTowards(_fillAmount, target, Time.deltaTime * _changingSpeed);
            // ждём конца кадра. Когда кадр закончится, эта функция перейдёт к следующей итерации цикла
            yield return waitForEndOfFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я чу-чуть отредактировал скрипт и всё работает! У меня еще маленький вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы восстановление срабатывало не сразу, а через пару секунд?

Comment: @sokilo, рад помочь. для этого достаточно в самом начале метода ChangeFillAmount дописать yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(секунды);  Однако в таком случае и уменьшение и увеличение будут сопровождаться этой задержкой. Если нужно чтобы задержка была только когда стремимся к единице, тогда следует сделать ещё два метода ChangeFillAmountToOne { yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(секунды);  yield return ChangeFillAmount(1)} и ChangeFillAmountToZero {yield return ChangeFillAmount(0)}. Не забудьте в StartSlow и StopSlow поменять ChangeFillAmount на соответствующие методы.