# Вопрос по методу Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моем коде Instantiate создает взрыв в позиции игрока

```
Instantiate(explosion, Player.Instance.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(90, Random.Range(0, 90), 0));
```

Но игрок на месте которого создается взрыв немного выглядывает из него. Удалять игрока при взрыве я не могу, поэтому нужно задать позицию создания взрыва немного выше по координате Y. Как можно такое провернуть?

Comment: Зайти в [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) и посмотреть, что означает `position` в параметрах, которые вы передаете методу `Instantiate`.

Comment: я уже смотрел и видел что это означает и понимаю что с этим значением ничего не получится. Думаю мне нужен метод в который я могу отдельно задать позиции X Y Z игрока. Но как именно это сделать я как раз не до конца понимаю

Comment: var spawnPosition = Player.Instance.transform.position; spawnPosition.y += 10(или любой отступ); Instantiate(explosion, spawnPosition, Quaternion.Euler(90, Random.Range(0, 90), 0)); Это было бы не так сложно, если бы вы сначала прочитали [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пробовал чтото подобное но писал transform.position.y что собственно не работало но я помнил что можно сделать нечто подобное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Instantiate(explosion, Player.Instance.transform.position + Vector.up, Quaternion.Euler(90, Random.Range(0, 90), 0));
```

1. Прибавляйте к `Player.Instance.transform.position` вектор с координатой y, если нужно приподнять взрыв повыше.
2. Уберите поворот по координате `x`, если проект двумерный.