# Хочу сохранить выбор сцены в Unity

Tags: unity3d

У меня игра кликер и там можно купить ОС (сцену) и надо чтобы когда мы выходили мы были на сцене которую купили (это не в 3д, метка не правильна). Всё работает одним кодом

[Код](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pmzI-vf0BDLeOf_6xUgd6Hf2EQzBUklG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ну надо так надо. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Вам сначала [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c), потом [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать PLayerPrefs как сказал другой человек, но если вам нужно будет сохранять более емкие данные, вам нужно будет использовать более защищённое и объёмное хранилище данных. На ютубе есть много обучающих видео. Просто напишите сохранение в юнити, советую использывать сериализацию и десириализацию(способ)

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранения значения используйте класс `PlayerPrefs`.
При покупке сцены вызывайте:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scene", 2);
```

А при входе в игру:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scene", 1));
```

Comment: Оно просто бесконечно загружает сцену, и играть нельзя

Comment: Создайте ещё одну и выполните выше перечисленное, Я немного исправлю ответ. Только поместите ее с индексом 0.