# Срабатывает триггер когда объект заходит в триггер, спрайт меняется когда объект выходит из тригера

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу сделать чтобы если объект заходит в триггер, тогда меняется его спрайт, а если не в триггере, а если не входит в триггер то спрайт другой. Но есть такая проблема, если спрайт изменился, то на другой уже никогда не изменяется. Когда объект на сером фоне, должна быть карта как на скрине, когда входит в триггер water(это вода на скрине) должен быть другой спрайт. к Заранее спасибо
код:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "water")
        {
            spriterenderer.sprite = spriteForCard;
             StartCoroutine(CheckForStay());
        }
        else
        {
            spriterenderer.sprite = spriteCard;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: у тебя прописано изменение спрайта только при входе в какой-либо тригер. На земле есть колайдер с тригером? 
Если нет, и если ты вышел из  объекта с тэгом "water" и не вошел в другой - то смены не будет.
Как вариант - накинуть колайдер-триггер на землю или прописать еще public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other), и в нём задать условия для смены спрайта при выходе из воды.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, все решается довольно примитивно, если подумать. В следующий раз советую пройти по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d), найти среди этих ресурсов тему, которая вам нужна и разобраться самому, нежели ждать, когда вам ответят на форуме, поигрывая тем временем в кс. За примитивным ответом можете отправиться по ссылке сверху, ниже мой вариант.

Разбиваем все на несколько компонентов. Первый - `Card`:

```
public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

    public void ChangeSprite(Sprite sprite)
    {
        _spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;
    }
        
    private void Start()
    {
        _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
}
```

Это, как можно понять из названия, скрипт, который висит на карте. В нем есть публичный метод `ChangeSprite`, который просто меняет спрайт карты на указанный в параметре.

Далее идет enum `SurfaceType`

```
public enum SurfaceType
{
    Water,
    Pocket,
        
}
```

Это обычное перечисление, которое хранит в себе всевозможные поверхности, на которые можно положить карту.

Далее `SurfaceHandler`

```
public class SurfaceHandler
{
    public static event Action<SurfaceType> SurfaceEntered;

    public void EnterSurface(SurfaceType type)
    {
        SurfaceEntered?.Invoke(type);
    }
        
}
```

Это класс, который просто вызывает событие, при вызове метода `EnterSurface`. Вообще, этот класс должен быть в одном экземпляре, но костылить синглтон я не захотел и просто сделал событие статичным.

Далее идет класс `Surface`

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class Surface : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SurfaceType _surfaceType;
        
    private SurfaceHandler _handler;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _handler = new SurfaceHandler();
        var collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        collider.isTrigger = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out Card card))
        {
            _handler.EnterSurface(_surfaceType);
        }
    }
}
```

Это класс поверхности, при входе в которую, у игрока будет меняться спрайт. `[RequireComponent]` нужен для того, чтобы на объекте, к которому прикреплен скрипт, всегда был нужный компонент. Класс в себе хранит тип поверхности, который нужно настроить в инспекторе. При коллизии, проверяется, является ли объект, вошедший в триггер, картой, вызывается метод `EnterSurface` у `SurfaceHandler` и передается тип поверхности. Далее класс `SpriteChanger` меняет спрайт у игрока.

```
public class SpriteChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Card _card;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _waterSprite;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _pocketSprite;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SurfaceHandler.SurfaceEntered += SwitchSpriteBySurface;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SurfaceHandler.SurfaceEntered -= SwitchSpriteBySurface;
    }

    private void SwitchSpriteBySurface(SurfaceType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case (SurfaceType.Water):
                _card.ChangeSprite(_waterSprite);
                break;
            case (SurfaceType.Pocket):
                _card.ChangeSprite(_pocketSprite);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Cant find sprite for type {type}");
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь, в `OnEnable` подписываемся на событие `SurfaceChanged`, а в `OnDisable` отписываемся. Следовательно, когда вызывается событие `SurfaceChanged`, срабатывает метод `SwitchSpriteBySurface`, который меняет спрайт у карты, в зависимости от того, на какую поверхность карта помещена.

Надеюсь, что я расписал все достаточно понятно, потому что код примитивный и понятно должно быть без объяснений. Также надеюсь, что расписывать, какой скрипт куда вешать не нужно, все итак из названий понятно. Главное не забудьте указать ссылки в инспекторе на все необходимое (`[SerializeField]` делает возможным отображение и установку значений в поля с модификатором доступа private)