# Как написать генерацию объектов в Юнити

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно заполнить игровое поле копиями объекта. Для начала я решил скопировать один объект, но он не отображается(как минимум). Я в Unity новичок и даже не представляю, как работает то, что написал. Можете объяснить, в чём проблема и как правильно это написать.
'''

```
public GameObject cell;

void Start()
{
    List<GameObject> a = new List<GameObject>();
    a.Add(Instantiate(cell, new Vector3(cell.transform.position.x * 3, cell.transform.position.y, cell.transform.position.z), cell.transform.rotation));
    a[0].SetActive(true);
}
```

'''

Comment: `Я в Unity новичок и даже не представляю, как работает то, что написал` Ну так загугли обучающие ресурсы по юнити, например их [туториалы](https://learn.unity.com/), которые помогут освоиться в юнити. После можешь зайти на [ulearn](https://ulearn.me/).

Comment: Я учусь в процессе. Туториалы это хорошо, но на английском и долго. Мне сейчас нужно решение. Можете ответить всё таки на вопрос?

Comment: `учусь в процессе` В процессе чего? Что ты в теории можешь сделать, если не знаешь даже основ? `на английском` Зайди на ютуб, гугл, любое другое место и поищи, там миллион видео, статей, курсов и т.д. в том числе и на русском. `долго` Пока ты ждал ответ здесь, ты мог уже сам загуглить, посмотреть любое видео или прочитать статью, в которой тебе бы все объяснили. Тебя никто не будет здесь учить основам, если хочешь обучаться сам - учись самостоятельно искать информацию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Кто тебя просил мне объяснять основы? Все, что я просил, - это код и комментарий о том, почему мои строки не работают. Все пункты(загуглить, посмотреть и тп) я уже выполнил и написал сюда, потому что не смог найти решение. Вместо того, чтобы посылать меня подальше, ты мог дать хотя бы одно из того, что я прошу, и подарить мне пищу для поисков и разборов. Разве не для этого такие порталы существуют?

Comment: `Можете объяснить, в чём проблема` Проблема в том, что ты не знаешь основ. `подарить мне пищу для поисков и разборов` Я тебе дал 3 ссылки, где за 10 минут можно найти ответ на твой вопрос, это ли не "пища для поисков и разборов"? `Все пункты(загуглить, посмотреть и тп) я уже выполнил` плохо выполнил буквально [ПЕРВАЯ](http://pogugli.com/?373769) ссылка в гугле - документация юнити, где написано что тебе нужно сделать. Неужели ждать 12 часов пока тебе ответят - быстрее, чем зайти в гугл и вписать 3 слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал это следующим образом, хотя лучше в таких случаях использовать пулы.

```
public GameObject original;
public List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

private void Start()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       CreateObject();
}

private void CreateObject()
{
   Vector3 position = original.position;
   postion.x += objects.Count;

   GameObject go = Instantiate(original, position, original.transform.rotation);
   go.SetActive(true);
   objects.Add(go);
}
```

Данный код создаёт 100 объектов, со смещением в 1 метр.

Answer (score -1):

```
public GameObject original; // сюда в поле инспектора суёшь тот объект который хочешь клонировать
void Start(){
    GameObject klon = (GameObject)Instantiate (original); // теперь создан объект klon который полостью соответствует объекту original
}
```