# Нужно ли учить C++ перед C# для unity(по гайдам из ютуба)

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я хотел начать разрабатывать игры на Unity и C# и не знаю, стоит ли мне перед этим учить C++ на более углубленном уровне, нежели основы. Я нашел [гайд](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEuUxy4Skpc&list=PLQOaTSbfxUtCrKs0nicOg2npJQYSPGO9r) на ютубе  по C++, в нем 204 видео. Также есть еще один [видеокурс](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyFWqbRfWIA&list=PLQOaTSbfxUtD6kMmAYc8Fooqya3pjLs1N) по C# от этого же канала(104 видео). Я не знаю, стоит ли мне действительно смотреть так много видеоуроков чтобы начать разрабатывать игры на Unity или стоит изучить лишь самые основы а потом приступать к изучению C# для геймдева и не тратить время

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137234/discussion-on-question-by------c--c--unity).

Answer (score 4):

С++ и C# это разные языки, и пусть у C# есть функционал C++, что может вам помочь, но всё же скорее это будет наоборот - помехой. Для того, чтобы писать на C# вам не нужно знать C++ (И для C++ C# естественно). Потому советую вам посмотреть эти 104 видео. И после каждого ролика пробовать функционал о котором узнал. После ищи гайды по unity, но главное для тебя - найти нормальный канал, не Хауди хо и Гошу Дударя, а (Желательно) узконаправленного человека который по истине знает C# и unity.

Comment: спасибо, я еще попробую книги по unity поискать если по нему есть хорошие книги

Comment: если те 104 видео такие же как те 204 по плюсам... то это будет очень плохой совет (я не знаю C# на том уровне, что бы оценивать качество материала, но канал вроде один и тот же)

Comment: полностью поддерживаю по поводу псевдо-специалистов на ютюбе, в основном там агрессивные болтуны и всякие проджект менеджеры. есть замечательные сайты с отличной подачей материала по конкретной технологии, а также учебные платформы с курсами (от профессиональных преподавателей).

Answer (score 3):

Раз уж началась дискуссия "какправильноилучше", то вставлю свою копейку. Я бы всё же посоветовал выучить основные основы C++ поскольку он больше приближен к железу чем C#, а соответственно придется немного узнать как работает железо. Но обучение начал я бы не с тех видео, что вы оставили в вопросе, а со следующих каналов:

1. [CodeBlog](https://www.youtube.com/c/CODEBLOG), тут хорошо про основные основы C# (его видео смотреть на 1.25 скорости)
2. [Andrey Shyrokoriadov](https://www.youtube.com/c/AndreyShyrokoriadov), тут хорошо про ООП и вот это вот всё.
3. [Dev Jugles](https://www.youtube.com/c/DevJungles), тут база по кишкам .NET
4. Ну и конечно же книги по [C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c) и [Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d) от коммьюнити ruSO

По юнити ничего не могу сказать, но определенно НЕ Гоша Дударь, НЕ Хауди Хо, НЕ Роман Сакутин.

Answer (score 3):

Учи минимум по C# и приступай к практике, параллельно углубляясь в тонкости C# и Unity, а так же сопутствующих тем, таких как алгоритмы и структуры данных(начни с "Грокаем алгоритмы"), ООП, SQL, NoSql, принципы программирования..

Если потом захочешь выучить С++ по нужде или из академического интереса, то флаг в руки.

Главное по дороге не рассыпать мотивацию, поэтому не отвлекайся)

Хочешь игры - делай игры! Хочешь C++? Кури C++! и т.д.

Comment: На самом деле важный вопрос для новичка, ибо на этом этапе задается вектор развития. Я помню как начинал, хватаясь за всё подряд и подсказать некому было, и тут не додумался спросить. Зачем минусовать ответы и закрывать вопрос?

Comment: *`Зачем минусовать ответы и закрывать вопрос?`* -- враги свободы не могут иначе