# ошибка CS1519, я не понимаю, что не так с моим кодом (я знаю что все) C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я буквально новичок. Это моя первая программа. Пишу простое приложение которое будет генерировать дикую магию для ДнД5. Юнити пишет либо error CS1519 и иногда error CS8124. Помогите пожалуйста

```
    ...

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Serializable;



public class WildMagic : MonoBehaviour
{
    static void Main(string[] args);
    //Массив под каждую дикую магию
    string[]WildMag = new string[21];
    var rnd = new Random();

        string [0] WildMag = "Изменение цвета кожи: Киньте D10 для определения цвета: 1-Зеленый 2-Синий 3-Красный 4-Черный 5-Желтый 6-Фиолетовый 7-Розовый 8-Коричневый 9-Белый 10-Серый";
        string [1] WildMag = "Дополнительная конечность : цель отращивает дополнительную конечность. Конечность не влияет на экипировку пользователя, не дает дополнительных атак и не влияет на большинство игровых ситуаций, но Мастер может постановить, что конечность налагает некоторые штрафы за обстоятельства в социальных ситуациях";
        string [2] WildMag = "Костующий маг получает +1D8 к спас броскам на 1 ход ";
        string [4] WildMag = "Огненный шар : Наносит урон — 4d6. Он поражает случайного человека; можно увернуться (18 и выше)";
        string [5] WildMag = "Икота : Цель неудержимо икает в течение следующего часа";
        string [6] WildMag = "Обеззараживание : Все в области 20 метров роняют свои оружия на землю";
        string [7] WildMag = "Рвота : Цель заклинателя должна прокинуть спас телосложения, иначе следующие 1D10 минут цель будет рвать";
        string [8] WildMag = "Коктельная вечеринка : Внезапно у вас и у каждого члена вашей группы в руке вместо любого другого предмета, который у них был раньше, появляется маленький стакан треугольной формы со странным алкогольным напитком с зеленой оливкой. Ваши предметы возвращаются после того как вы выпьите данный напиток";
        string [9] WildMag = "Неожиданный гость : Перед вами внезапно появляется говорящий слон, он объясняет, что ему очень жаль, что он не появился раньше, и уходит, напевая";
        string [10] WildMag = "Снег : В радиусе 200 футов начинает падать снег. Снег будет появляться даже в помещениях. Снег продолжает падать 1D4 часов";
        string [11] WildMag = "В следующий раз повезет : Сразу же кастуйте второй раз дикую магию. В этот раз эффект будет только на вас";
        string [12] WildMag = "Дым : Облако дыма появляется в 100 футах в случайном направлении от вас.";
        string [13] WildMag = "Кислотный : заклинатель и цель получают 1d6 единиц урона кислотой.";
        string [14] WildMag = "Сильный вкус : сильный вкус из-за рта пахнет у кого-то случайным образом в пределах 10 футов от заклинателя (по умолчанию заклинатель, если в пределах досягаемости никого нет). Бросьте 1D6 для определения вкуса: 1-Лук,2-Пиво,3-Конский навоз,4-Чеснок,5-Капуста,6-ваниль. Длится 3d10 минут";
        string [15] WildMag = "Танцуй, друг мой : танец фей воздействует на вашего ближайшего друга, где бы он ни находился (сохранение стандарта, эффекта, уровня заклинателя). Танцует ровно один танец";
        string [16] WildMag = "Рога : у вас постоянно растет пара маленьких рогов на лбу. Контраст с цветом вашей кожи. Снятие проклятия может удалить их.";
        string [17] WildMag = "Запах волка : цель испускает запах хищника в течение следующего часа. Домашние животные, в том числе собаки и лошади, изначально настроены враждебно. Существа, выслеживающие выпившего по запаху, получают +1D4 к своим проверкам Выслеживания, пока действует эффект.";
        string [18]WildMag = "Стоп : Абсолютно ничего не происходит. Вы не можете колдовать магию в течении 1d4 раундов";
        string [19]WildMag = "Пение : заклинатель должен преуспеть в броске Телосложения, иначе он будет вынужден петь до своего следующего действия. Пение не позволяет человеку накладывать заклинания, если только он не обучен накладывать заклинания с помощью песни.";
        string[20] WildMag = "Крысы : Вы оказываетесь в окружении 1d100 крыс.";

    Console.WriteLine.WildMag[rnd.Next(0, WildMag.Length)]
}
    ...
```

Comment: Вам очень далеко еще до Unity и 3d игрушек, ибо вы, не зная основ, лезете сразу в пламя. Вот давайте по порядку `static void Main(string[] args);` - что это? На вид это стартовая точка **консольного проекта**, но почему она в (как понимаю скрипте) Unity? Далее, тот же самый код, разве методы так закрываются (`возвращаемыйТип Имя (типАргумента имяАргумента);`)? Да вроде нет, ибо методы всегда **должны иметь тело**, то есть `{ }`, а не `;`. Точка с запятой используется в переменных. Далее `Console.WriteLine.WildMag[rnd.Next(0, WildMag.Length)]` - тоже консоль, и тоже ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: Про всякие `string [8] WildMag` я промолчу... И вот как бы, вы полезли в пламя, ничерта не понимая, не зная даже сааамых основ, но зато хотите что-то от комьюнити. Вопрос только что? Чтоб научили? Ну, это не к нам. Чтоб объяснили, что не так? Ок, а смысл? Вы через пол часа придете по новой, ибо на след. строке уже опять будет ошибка синтаксиса. Мой совет, начните с основ, напишите простой консольный проект, выучите синтаксис языка, а уж потом юнити.

Comment: Также книги unity3d - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/191482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*что не так с моим кодом* - всё не так.

https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ - потратьте пару вечеров, поучите C#. Самые основы хотя-бы. Когда вы сами поймёте что это не код, а жесть и каша, можете начинать учить Unity и узнаете, что там ни System.Random, не System.Console не используется.

Ну вот вам, для начала.

```
public class WildMagic : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] WildMag = new string[]
    {
        "Изменение цвета кожи: Киньте D10 для определения цвета: 1-Зеленый 2-Синий 3-Красный 4-Черный 5-Желтый 6-Фиолетовый 7-Розовый 8-Коричневый 9-Белый 10-Серый", 
        "Дополнительная конечность : цель отращивает дополнительную конечность. Конечность не влияет на экипировку пользователя, не дает дополнительных атак и не влияет на большинство игровых ситуаций, но Мастер может постановить, что конечность налагает некоторые штрафы за обстоятельства в социальных ситуациях",
        "Костующий маг получает +1D8 к спас броскам на 1 ход ",
        "Огненный шар : Наносит урон — 4d6. Он поражает случайного человека; можно увернуться (18 и выше)",
        "Икота : Цель неудержимо икает в течение следующего часа",
        "Обеззараживание : Все в области 20 метров роняют свои оружия на землю",
        "Рвота : Цель заклинателя должна прокинуть спас телосложения, иначе следующие 1D10 минут цель будет рвать",
        "Коктельная вечеринка : Внезапно у вас и у каждого члена вашей группы в руке вместо любого другого предмета, который у них был раньше, появляется маленький стакан треугольной формы со странным алкогольным напитком с зеленой оливкой. Ваши предметы возвращаются после того как вы выпьите данный напиток", 
        "Неожиданный гость : Перед вами внезапно появляется говорящий слон, он объясняет, что ему очень жаль, что он не появился раньше, и уходит, напевая",
        "Снег : В радиусе 200 футов начинает падать снег. Снег будет появляться даже в помещениях. Снег продолжает падать 1D4 часов",
        "В следующий раз повезет : Сразу же кастуйте второй раз дикую магию. В этот раз эффект будет только на вас",
        "Дым : Облако дыма появляется в 100 футах в случайном направлении от вас.",
        "Кислотный : заклинатель и цель получают 1d6 единиц урона кислотой.",
        "Сильный вкус : сильный вкус из-за рта пахнет у кого-то случайным образом в пределах 10 футов от заклинателя (по умолчанию заклинатель, если в пределах досягаемости никого нет). Бросьте 1D6 для определения вкуса: 1-Лук,2-Пиво,3-Конский навоз,4-Чеснок,5-Капуста,6-ваниль. Длится 3d10 минут",
        "Танцуй, друг мой : танец фей воздействует на вашего ближайшего друга, где бы он ни находился (сохранение стандарта, эффекта, уровня заклинателя). Танцует ровно один танец",
        "Рога : у вас постоянно растет пара маленьких рогов на лбу. Контраст с цветом вашей кожи. Снятие проклятия может удалить их.",
        "Запах волка : цель испускает запах хищника в течение следующего часа. Домашние животные, в том числе собаки и лошади, изначально настроены враждебно. Существа, выслеживающие выпившего по запаху, получают +1D4 к своим проверкам Выслеживания, пока действует эффект.",
        "Стоп : Абсолютно ничего не происходит. Вы не можете колдовать магию в течении 1d4 раундов",
        "Пение : заклинатель должен преуспеть в броске Телосложения, иначе он будет вынужден петь до своего следующего действия. Пение не позволяет человеку накладывать заклинания, если только он не обучен накладывать заклинания с помощью песни.",
        "Крысы : Вы оказываетесь в окружении 1d100 крыс."
    };

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(WildMag[Random.Range(WildMag.Length)]);
    }
}
```

Вывод произойдет в отладочную консоль редактора Unity при запуске игры.