# Как оптимизировать код для присвоения компонента переменной после проверки его наличия в if-условии?

Tags: c#, unity3d, if

Совершая проверку в if на наличие компонента, могу ли я сразу поместить его в переменную, вместо того чтобы вызвать компонент повторно после проверки ?

Посмотрим. к примеру что-то вроде этого

```
if(new a reg = collider.GetComponent<a>()){ }
```

Не особо шарю за с#, и вобще за тему программирования. и задался вопросом а могу ли? Ну просто тут я так думаю, вызываю в проверке гет компонент у объекта, а сразу после проверки мне нужно присвоить его переменной, но вместо того чтобы ещё раз вызывать гет компонент я хочу сразу поместить его в переменную. Правда не шарю каким образом. Не то чтобы это было для меня прям критично, просто меня мучает мой внутренний перфекционист. Хочется чтобы, все было сделано красиво.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте грамматические ошибки, стиль речи и форматирование. Перенесите заголовок в вопрос, уберите из вопроса лишнее — вас сложно понять.

Comment: Можно, но я бы не советовал мешать разные операции в одном месте - это и читать сложнее, и дебажить

Comment: Сделаю все красиво как только разберусь как тут все работает

Comment: [TryGetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609900/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-unity3d)

Comment: 10 раз было написано "не шарю"... Так возьмите книгу и почитайте...

Comment: Подумав свежей головой понял что мне нужно было создать что-то вроде локальной переменной

Comment: `if (collider.TryGetComponent<a>(out a reg)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Либо вы спрашиваете элементарное, либо я не понял вопроса:

```cs
var reg = collider.GetComponent<a>();
if (reg ...)
{
    ...
}
```

Правда, что именно вы проверяете - непонятно из вашего кода, он некорректный.

Comment: Мне нужно присвоить компонент объекта. переменной. во время проверки в if на наличие этого компонента. При условии что этот компонент есть на обекте(если его не будет присвоится же null туплю)

Comment: @Сем так используйте `TryGetComponent`, в комментариях под вопросом ссылка.