# Ресурсы где можно изучать Unity после среднего уровня?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я могу писать средние по сложности проекты, но постоянно упираюсь в барьер когда хочу повысить сложность. Посоветуйте ресурсы где можно повысить уровень.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609901/373567