Делал по курсу. Там всё работало. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Unity. С#


using UnityEngine;  
using System.Collections;  
using UnityEngine.UI;  
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;  
  
public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour {  
  
    public Sprite button, pressed;  
    public bool music;  
      
    private Image img;  
  
    void Start () {  
        img = GetComponent <Image> ();  
    }  
  
    void OnMouseDown () {  
        img.sprite = pressed; // Тут ошибка  
    }  
  
    void OnMouseUp () {  
        img.sprite = button; // И тут  
  
    }  
  
}



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Забыли компонент Image на объект навесить в редакторе. Поэтому GetComponent<Image>() возвращает null.

@aepot Я не понял.

@pavelsamosin говорт, книгу вам надо по юнити прочитать, где все основы расписаны, либо очень и очень внимательно смотреть каждую деталь на видео без отвлекания..... а если уверены что ничего не пропустили, тогда возвращаемся: надо прочитать книгу по основам по Юнити

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/191482 - список книг

Я делал всё по курсу

GetComponent<Image>() откуда вам достать должен готовый компонент Image? Оно магическим образом на объекте на сцене не появится.

Щас скрин прикреплю

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37774870/12888024

Делал по курсу. Там всё работало - пересматривайте курс, ищите, что вы упустили.

Пересмотрел 1000000000000000000000000 раз, не работает.
