# Дайте мануал по client-side сайтам на JavaScript

Tags: django

Привет. Делаю сейчас одно приложение с гуйнёй на вебе. Начал делать на Джанге, да вот беда, понял что не хочется возиться с джанговкой идеологией форм и ввода данных. Захотелось вот написать прикладуху на яваскрипте а на сервере только простейший бэкенд оставить, вынеся всю логику на клиента.

Но опыта даже приблизительно такой работы нету у меня.

Всвязи с этим вопрос - что почитать про JS Client-Side сайты? Общая концепция, экземплы, туториалы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript)

Comment: Меня интересует не яваскрипт, или джиквери сами по себе, а именно инструкции по созданию полноценных сайтов на клиенте, чтобы к примеру там были шаблонизаторы, аякс, рест и прочая подобная фигня