# Где находится переменная созданная через оператор `let`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

При создании переменной через оператор `let`, я не могу ее найти в глобальном объекте `window`. Где она находиться?

> На верхнем уровне скриптов и функций `let`, в отличии от `var`, не создает
>   свойства на глобальном объекте. Например:

```
var x = 'global_x';
let y = 'global_y';
console.log(this.x); // 'global_x'
console.log(this.y); // undefined
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69644/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ух, тут не всё так просто. И `let` и `var` - глобальны, да, но...

Глобальная область неоднородна и состоит из [Declarative environment records (DER) и object environment records (OER)](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1).

Согласно ECMA спеке, только *FunctionDeclarations*, *GeneratorDeclarations*, и *VariableStatements* создаются в OER, чем в общем случае является `window`.

Остальное (`const` и `let`) находятся в DER.

В общем, и `let`, и `var` глобальны, но `var`'ы в объекте `window`, тогда как `let`'ы в декларативной области, которую вы не можете пощупать. Это похоже на случай, когда вы не можете обратиться к переменной в области видимости функции извне этой функции.

## Более подробно в [спеке](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-environment-records):

- [Object Environment Records](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-environment-records).
- [Declarative Environment Records](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-declarative-environment-records).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можете подсказать литературу для более глубокого изучение javascript по мимо спецификации ибо с английским не лады)

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный вот есть тред про это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript

Comment: [10.2.1 Записи окружений](http://es5.javascript.ru/x10.html#x10.2.1). `Декларативные записи окружения используются, чтобы определить действие таких синтаксических элементов языка ECMAScript, как FunctionDeclaration, VariableDeclaration и выражения Catch, которые напрямую ассоциируют привязки идентификатора со значениями языка ECMAScript.`  Я может что - то не понимаю, но я заметил противоречие. Так `FunctionDeclarations`, `GeneratorDeclarations`, и `VariableStatements` принадлежат `OER` или `DER`?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный странно всё это. В этой спеке https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-environment-records говорится: "The object Environment Record component of a global Environment Record contains the bindings for all built-in globals and all bindings introduced by a FunctionDeclaration, GeneratorDeclaration, or VariableStatement contained in global code". Так что, OER они принадлежат.