# W3C Security Policy.

Tags: javascript, html, css, xss

Интересует какая-нибудь книга, или хороший ман по w3c. Как искать уязвимости, как их эксплуатировать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript)

Comment: @Air это вопрос не про js конкретно, но и про него в т.ч. -- не дубликат ни разу.

Comment: Это дубликат...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content Security Policy: Level-1](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/)

[Content Security Policy: Level-2](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/)