# onclick по разным объектам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью **Js** или **jQuery** сделать возможность взаимодействия с двумя разными объектами.

Чтобы при клике по `объект_1` появлялся `объект_2` и при клике на него же (второй объект) он скрывался. Если говорить совсем просто то тыкаем на первый появляется второй при клике на второй второй скрывается и чтобы это можно было повторять а не одноразовое действие (где проделал этот алгоритм а на второй раз он не работает уже, пока не перезагрузишь страницу)

Comment: А что-то сами уже пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

В чём у Вас возникла проблема?
Включим логику:
На первый элемент повесим поиск второго, его скроем/покажем.
На втором просто обратимся к себе (через `this`, например) и скроем его (обрабатывать показ нет смысла).

---

Вот крайне любезно выпрошенное решение:

```js
$(_ => {
  $('#obj1').on('click', e => {
    $('#obj2').toggle();
  });
  $('#obj2').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='obj1'>Show the #2 object</div>
<hr />
<div id='obj2'>Click on me for hide</div>
```

Comment: в том что я плохо представляю как это все написать в код.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин, Если такую простую задачу не можете выполнить - начните с основ учебника, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/207618) хороший список.

Comment: мне бы решение моего вопроса а не советы с:

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин, В таком случае советую обратиться на сайты с фриланс-услугами, тут мы **помогаем** решить вопрос, а не решаем за автора.