# Кака покрасить все буквы заданном элементе в различные случайные цвета?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Покрасьте все буквы текста в заданном элементе в различные случайные цвета.
Список цветов должен хранится в массиве.

Comment: А вы, простите, что пытались сделать, и что получилось? Как покрасить данную букву текста, знаете? Как получить случайное число, знаете? Как получить по индексу цвет из массива, знаете? Цикл for знаете? Если вы всего этого _не_ знаете, вам стоит посмотреть [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/10105).

Answer (score 4):

[Поиск элементов в DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom).
[Получение и вставка содержимого в элемент](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document).
[Обращение к символам строки](https://javascript.ru/string/charat).
[Получаем случайный элемент массива](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/random-from-array).
[Перебирающие методы](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration).

Пожалуйста, используйте эти знания для решения Вашей задачи.