# Определить на какой элемент нажал пользователь

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 10 кнопок с одинаковым классом на сайте. Нужно определить на какой из 10 кнопок я нажал.

Comment: Для чего именно определять? В колбэк функции клика `this` будет указывать на тот самый объект

Comment: Можете прислать пример кодом, а то я не совсем понимаю(

Comment: Можете открыть учебник "javascript для чайников" и начать с азов, в которых всё это написано

Comment: смотрите как много: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/199253)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам в обработчике приходит `this`, который указывает на нажатый элемент

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    const el = $(this);
    console.log(el.text(), el.data("btn"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-btn="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-btn="2">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn" data-btn="3">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn" data-btn="4">Button 4</button>
<button class="btn" data-btn="5">Button 5</button>
<button class="btn" data-btn="6">Button 6</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var target = event.target;

  if (target.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;

  target.style.background = 'black';
})
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button class='ten'></button>
<button class='ten'></button>
<button class='ten'></button>
<button class='ten'></button>
<button class='ten'></button>
```

С помощью `target`

Comment: Представляете, на странице есть сложная таблица со вложенностями, различные вспомогательные контролы, тулбары, меню, футер и еще куча всего. И в итоге у вас запрос обходит это всё. Это же жесть))