# Зачем Javascript нужна консоль

Tags: javascript, консоль

Зачем Javascript нужна консоль.
Всем привет,
У меня вопрос, почему javascript использует console.log. Например, ни один клиент не смотрит на консоль.

Comment: Консоль это инструмент разработчика, который позволяет вывести отладочную информацию (и не только) не мешая пользователю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Она нужна писателю, а не пользователю. Ну например:

1. Не реализован пользовательский интерфейс, некуда выводить данные (в частности - учебные задачи). Можно выводить результат кода через console.log и убедиться, что он работает правильно.
2. Что-то вычисляется из множества переменных (циклов / вызовов) и получается неверный результат: Пошагово расставить в коде console.log и выводить значения переменных в разных местах, позапускать код, пока не поймаете причину ошибки.
3. Попался сложный алгоритм с хитрыми циклами, надо разобраться что в нем происходит: Сразу можно расставить на каждой итерации console.log со всеми переменными, позапускать - смотреть, как работает.
4. Банально запустить однострочный код и что-то быстро посчитать / преобразовать / сортировать. Собрать какие-то данные из таблицы на каком-нибудь сайте.

Помимо `.log()` у console есть еще несколько методов.

5. `console.warn("# исправить функцию")` — Можно оставить самому себе такие сообщения. Написал какой-нибудь кусок быстро и некачественно? При запуске кода пусть постоянно мазолит глаза желтым и напоминет, что там кое-что надо переписать. Что-то сверхважное среди остальных предупреждений можно временно отметить через `console.error()` - сообщение будет красным.
6. Функция вызывает функцию, которая вызывает функцию, которая вызывает функцию... Ошибки нет, но хочется проверить, кто-кого вызвал. `console.trace()`
7. `console.table()` выводит данные из объектов в виде таблицы. Нужен, чтобы хвастаться, что вы о нем знали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Там есть список всех методов >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

Comment: Пункты 2 и 3 - ЧТО???))) Отладка - нет, не слышали?)))

Comment: @СергейМишин Ну спросили, для чего нужна консоль, а она вполне может быть использована в этих целях. Одно не исключает другое)

Comment: спасибо за ответ.Я поставил лайк.И типер мне появился новый вопрос какие курси есть для javascript? 

Comment: @AsqarArslonov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript — Там большой список) Обратите внимание на 9-й пункт.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо большое:)

Answer (score 2):

Консоль JavaScript, как и любая другая, нужна для того, чтобы писать в ней код. `console.log()` выводит сообщения, которые помогают понять что произошло, например, при использовании в `try-catch`. Пользователям она не нужна, но она нужна как обратная связь для тестировщиков, чтобы сообщать разработчикам какой выведен код ошибки после таких-то действий.

Comment: оҳо,спасибо за ответ очен кратко но понятно