# как сделать так, чтобы пропала иконка при нажатии?

Tags: html, css, display

СSS. хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на иконку она пропала, но разве есть такой псевдокласс?(я новичок, извиниите за тупой вопрос)

Answer (score 3):

Без дополнительных оберток в HTML - никак.

Можно сделать с помощью невидимого `checkbox` и селектора `:checked`

```css
.hide-icon {
  display: none;
}

.hide-icon:checked + img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="hide-icon" type="checkbox">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/8af70de8af94c64bb97836ac22203322.png">
</label>

<label>
  <input class="hide-icon" type="checkbox">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/ad98053db7e34527c398c2be74f2706b.png">
</label>

<label>
  <input class="hide-icon" type="checkbox">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/cfe8b956895ec05df18a78466ced1cb4.png">
</label>
```

---

Или без этого всего, через JavaScript:

```html
<img class="js-hide" src="https://gyazo.com/8af70de8af94c64bb97836ac22203322.png">
<img class="js-hide" src="https://gyazo.com/ad98053db7e34527c398c2be74f2706b.png">
<img class="js-hide" src="https://gyazo.com/cfe8b956895ec05df18a78466ced1cb4.png">

<script>
  let images = document.querySelectorAll(".js-hide");

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", hide);
  }

  function hide() {
    this.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

>> [Книги и учебные ресурсы по javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Развивая идею @OPTIMUS PRIME с чекбоксом, и учитывая что не сказано про тип элемента иконки, вот возможно рабочее решение из одного элемента:

```css
.icon {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("https://pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/3199659271606252959-512.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  outline: none;
}

.icon:checked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="icon">
```