# Как сделать несколько независимых друг от друга слайдеров на одной WEB-странице? (на чистом JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Суть проблемы: Мне необходимо расположить **несколько слайдеров на одной странице.** Примерно понимаю как это можно сделать, но написать код не могу, не до конца разобрался во всем.
Как я понимаю эти слайдеры должны быть одного класса, но с разными id. При этом каждый слайдер обрабатывается одной и той же функцией, которая двигает слайды с тем id, что и у кнопки.**(каждый слайдер работает независимо от остальных слайдеров)**

Слайдер желательно на **чистом js** и с **комментариями** как у меня, чтобы я хоть что-то понял:)

```js
// Берём кнопку вперёд
let btnNext = document.querySelector("#btnNext");
// Берём слайды
let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
// Объявляем переменную i
let i = 0;

// Объявляем событие нажатия на кнопку вперёд
btnNext.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Увеличиваем переменную i
  ++i
  // Условие если переменная i больше или равна количеству слайдов
  if (i >= slides.length) {
    // Удаляем класс block предыдущему слайду
    slides[i - 1].classList.remove("block");
    // Присваиваем переменной i ноль
    i = 0;
    // Добавляем класс block следующему слайду
    slides[i].classList.add("block");
  } else { // Иначе
    // Удаляем класс block предыдущему слайду
    slides[i - 1].classList.remove("block");
    // Добавляем класс block следующему слайду
    slides[i].classList.add("block");

  }
})
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Слайдер</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides" id="sl0">
      <img src="" style="background: blue;" class="slide block" id="sl0" alt="">
      <img src="" style="background: red;" class="slide" id="sl0" alt="">
      <img src="" style="background: green;" class="slide" id="sl0" alt="">
    </div>
    <button id="btnNext" id="sli0">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides" id="sl1">
      <img src="" style="background: blue;" class="slide block" id="sl1" alt="">
      <img src="" style="background: red;" class="slide" id="sl1" alt="">
      <img src="" style="background: green;" class="slide" id="sl1" alt="">
    </div>
    <button class="btnNext" id="sli1">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js" class="btnNext" id="sl1"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Просьба за глупости сильно не ругать, зеленый еще)

Comment: А кнопку для перехода к предыдущему слайду забыли...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не-а, не обязательно использовать разные `id`. Наоборот, можно написать универсальный код, используя названия классов, который будет работать с любым количеством слайдеров.

> ...желательно с комментариями...

```js
let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
// sliders - список всех элементов с классом class="slider"
// sliders[0] — первый элемент, sliders[1] — второй, sliders[i] — i-тый.

for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
  // Перебирает все, вызывает функцию для каждого.
  init_slider(sliders[i]);
}

function init_slider(slider) {
  // Значение slider: Очередной sliders[i], переданный при вызове функции.
  
  let slide = slider.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  // Вместо document.query... Получается список всех class="slide"
  // которые находятся где-то внутри текущего элемента slider.
  
  let next = slider.querySelector('.next');
  // Кнопка next внутри этого slider.
  
  let i = 0;
  // Номер текущего "открытого" слайда.
  
  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slide[i].classList.remove('block');
    // slide[i] - открытый слайд. Скрываем.
    
    i = (i + 1) % slide.length; // (*1)
    
    slide[i].classList.add('block');
    // slide[i] - следующий слайд. Показываем.
  });  
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.slides {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <img style="background: blue;" class="slide block">
    <img style="background: red;" class="slide">
    <img style="background: green;" class="slide">
  </div>
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <img style="background: blue;" class="slide block">
    <img style="background: red;" class="slide">
    <img style="background: green;" class="slide">
  </div>
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

**(*1)** `i = (i + 1) % slide.length;` — `a % b` дает остаток от деления `a` на `b`.

В этом примере `slide.length == 3`, получается:

```
                                                     i было | стало
(0 + 1) % 3  →  1   // 1 не делится на 3            ||    0       1
(1 + 1) % 3  →  2   // 2 не делится на 3            ||    1       2
(2 + 1) % 3  →  0   // 3 делится на 3, остаток - 0. ||    2       0

... зацикливается, и без if-else :)
```

---

[>> Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript#answer-474386)

Answer (score 2):

Можно отталкиваться от нажатого эл-та.

Сразу немного о "магии" используемой далее в коде, а конкретно о строке

```
currentIndex = [...slides].indexOf(block.querySelector('.slide.block'));
```

`[]` - обозначает массив (практически, это new Array() в сокращенном виде)

`...` - так называемый, оператор расширения (читать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/rest-parameters-spread-operator#spread-operator)), вкратце, он говорит нам "добавить/извлечь в массив все эл-ты". Не путать с [остаточными параметрами](https://learn.javascript.ru/rest-parameters-spread-operator#ostatochnye-parametry)!

Суммируя, мы берём все найденные слайды (slides) и извлекаем их в массив, ну а дальше уже ищем индекс эл-та в массиве, используя [indexOf()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#indexof-lastindexof-i-includes)

```js
// Берём все кнопки "вперёд"
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.btnNext");

// циклом проходимся по каждой кнопке
buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  // Объявляем событие нажатия на кнопку вперёд
  button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    // находим "блок" слайдера
    let block = evt.target.closest('.slider'),
        // для ранее найденного блока берём все слайды
        slides = block.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
        // находим индекс активного слайда
        currentIndex = [...slides].indexOf(block.querySelector('.slide.block'));
        // находим индекс следующего слайда
        // если текущий слайд последний - начинаем "с нуля"
        nextIndex = currentIndex < (slides.length-1) ? currentIndex+1 : 0;
    // удаляем класс у текущего слайда
    slides[currentIndex].classList.remove("block");
    // добавляем класс следующему слайду
    slides[nextIndex].classList.add("block");
  })
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides" id="sl0">
    <img src="" style="background: blue;" class="slide " id="sl0" alt="">
    <img src="" style="background: red;" class="slide " id="sl0" alt="">
    <img src="" style="background: green;" class="slide block" id="sl0" alt="">
  </div>
  <button class="btnNext" id="sli0">NEXT</button>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides" id="sl1">
    <img src="" style="background: blue;" class="slide block" id="sl1" alt="">
    <img src="" style="background: red;" class="slide" id="sl1" alt="">
    <img src="" style="background: green;" class="slide" id="sl1" alt="">
  </div>
  <button class="btnNext" id="sli1">NEXT</button>
</div>
<script src="app.js" class="btnNext" id="sl1"></script>
```

**P.S. ВАЖНО!** Не может быть у одного эл-та несколько одинаковых атрибутов (у Вас, `<button id="btnNext" id="sli0">NEXT</button>`), так же, не может быть одинаковых id на странице (у Вас - всё тот же button с `id="btnNext"`)

Comment: Новички имеют свойство падать в обморок при виде "троеточия" без справок )

Comment: Ахах).. Добавил небольшой разбор.