# В полученном массиве чисел, вернуть сумму всех положительных чисел. JavaSript

Tags: javascript

Задание:

> Вы получаете массив чисел, возвращаете сумму всех положительных чисел.
>
> Пример [1,-4,7,12] => 1 + 7 + 12 = 20
>
> Примечание: если суммировать нечего, сумма по умолчанию равна 0.

Мое решение:

```
function positiveSum(arr) {
  return arr.filter(i => i > 0).map(i => x+=i, x=0).reverse()[0]
}
```

Почему-то он выдает мне ошибку, не могу понять. Хотя должен вернуть цифру.

> Test Results:
> Basic tests
> Testing for fixed tests
> expected undefined to equal 0
> Completed in 2ms
> Completed in 2ms

Comment: "если суммировать нечего, сумма по умолчанию равна 0" прямо в самом задании написано

Comment: только не пойму через что это сделать?

Comment: через if ....в самом начале кода например

Comment: function positiveSum(arr) {
  if (arr.filter(i => i > 0).map(i => x+=i, x=0).reverse()) return arr[0]
else return 0;
}

Comment: expected 1 to equal 15
Ошибку выдает все равно)

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что надо обязательно всё свой выражение в if  запихнуть? тебе надо просто проверить входной параметр

Comment: подсказка.....на вход что можно подать в функцию, кроме массива........а если массив, то какой длины он может быть?

Comment: вообще не догоняю(

Comment: ответь на два вопроса......

Comment: вопросы не догоняю))

Comment: окей....начнём с простого......массивы какой длины можно подать на вход в  функцию?

Comment: Я не понимаю вопроса, что значит подать какой длины.

Comment: на вход в функцию ты даёшь массив....как аргумент....так?

Comment: видимо я плохо учился(

Comment: Я тупо не понимаю вопросов

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474386/191482  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Спасибо конечно) книги вообще не могу читать, учусь по видео,

Comment: Ну, результат налицо ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да просто не доходит до меня от книг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую вам прочитать про reduce. Не такой уж и сложный метод в массиве.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Вот решение:

```
const arr =  [1,-4,7,12]
function positiveSum(arr) {
  return arr.filter(i => i > 0).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Не очень понимаю зачем несколько раз по массиву надо проходиться и зачем писать код, который сам же потом не можешь модифицировать

Если уж однострочными методами вам сложно, то вам надо начать с самый простых и очевидных реализаций, например через самый обычный цикл `for`:

```js
const sumOfPositives = (arr = []) => {
  let sum = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {    
    if (arr[i] > 0) sum += arr[i];
  }
  
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfPositives([1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3]));
console.log(sumOfPositives([-1, -2, -3]));
console.log(sumOfPositives([]));
console.log(sumOfPositives());
```

Потом можно переписать с помощью `for..of`:

```js
const sumOfPositives = (arr = []) => {
  let sum = 0;
  
  for (const num of arr) {
    if (num > 0) sum += num;
  }
  
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfPositives([1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3]));
console.log(sumOfPositives([-1, -2, -3]));
console.log(sumOfPositives([]));
console.log(sumOfPositives());
```

А потом уже можно писать однострочные ответы, например так:

```js
const sumOfPositives = (arr = []) => arr.reduce((sum, num) => num > 0 ? sum += num : sum, 0);

console.log(sumOfPositives([1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3]));
console.log(sumOfPositives([-1, -2, -3]));
console.log(sumOfPositives([]));
console.log(sumOfPositives());
```