# Что требуется сделать в этом задании, и поэтапно как работает этот код?

Tags: javascript

**Задача звучит так**: Задано n. Составить квадраты: 1 * 1 + 3 * 3 + 5 * 5+ ... +(2n – 1)*(2n – 1).
Сумму сохранить в переменной sum.
**Так выглядит решение:**
[image: не могу понять к чему тут эти "i"]

просто я только начал изучать JS и этот код и эта задача мне вообще не понятна

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно? Все используемые здесь вещи описаны в первых главах любого учебника https://learn.javascript.ru/variables / https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for / https://learn.javascript.ru/operators

Comment: Извините, я настолько не понимаю задачу и решение что не могу внятно сформульровать мой вопрос.
Почему в условии сразу не написали что (1 в квадрате, 3 в квадрате и тд.)
Еще вторая строка кода не понята, что это за манипуляции с "i"

Comment: Потому что никакой разницы нет, как захотелось, так и написали. Javascript тут уже ни при чём, это обычная школьная математика

Comment: Про вторую строку я уже говорил, что это описано в первых главах любого учебника https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for

Comment: Вторая строка: "Пусть i равно 1;  i меньше либо равно n; i увеличивается на еденицу" 
я знаю функции операторов, я не вижу смысла во второй строке.
P. s. И как я такой недалёкий собрался выучить JS

Comment: Смысл второй строки подробно расписан в первых главах любого учебника https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript)

Comment: @ТрубенковТимур `как я такой недалёкий собрался выучить JS`  а вы читали книги по JS прежде чем смотреть код? Есть ощущение что вы просто решили смотреть любой код и сразу иметь знание что происходит. А надо изначально книгу для новичков прочитать. Вы пробовали для начала это сделать?  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript

Comment: @АндрейШишкин читал но не полностью

Comment: @ТрубенковТимур Вот для начала прочитайте полностью. Там все основные конструкции, включая циклы, массивы, счётчики описаны. Нет смысла пытаться сразу написать операционную систему, если вы даже с основами языка не ознакомились до конца

Answer (score -1):

В задаче требуется получить сумму квадратов нечетных чисел. Количество нечетных чисел задается от 1 до n.

```
// До какого числа в числовой последовательности выполнять расчеты
// например берем числовую последовательность 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
// три нечетных числа в этой последовательности это 1 3 5
// соответственно сумма квадратов равна 1 * 1 + 3 * 3 + 5 * 5 = 35
let n = 3;

// создаем переменную для хранения конечного результата
let sum = 0;

// создаем цикл который будет в переменной i
// генерировать числовую последовательность от 1 до n включительно
for (let i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
    // Формула по которой находим из числовой последовательности
    // нечетные числа и получаем сумму их квадратов 
    sum += (2 * i - 1)**2;
}

// Выводим результат в консоль
console.log(sum); //35
```