# Когда следует использовать this.?

Tags: javascript, консоль

Есть код для консоли браузера

```
const person = {
  name: ['Bob', 'Smith'],
  age: 32,
  gender: 'male',
  interests: ['music', 'skiing'],
  bio: function() {
    alert(this.name[0] + ' ' + this.name[1] + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.interests[0] + ' and ' + this.interests[1] + '.');
  },
  greeting: function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name[0] + '.');
  }
};
```

Когда вообще следует использовать это чтобы не было ошибок?

Убрав this.  name из массива вызывается с ошибкой

Comment: Когда прочитайте про [него](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)..

Comment: Потому что в текущем пространстве имён не существует переменной с именем name

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript)

Comment: Если вы хотите получить свойство текущего объекта — значит используйте this. Если не хотите — значит не используйте. Непонятно, какого ответа вы ещё ожидаете