# Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика

Tags: книги

Рекомендуемая литература и документация по знаниям и навыкам разработки, не привязанным к конкретным языкам и платформам.

Все эти книги следовало бы добавить в каждый [список литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/181472), но мы следуем принципу DRY и сохраняем их здесь, в одном месте.

**Дополнения к ответу всячески приветствуются!**

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## Архитектура ПО

- *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs - 2nd Edition*. Harold Abelson, Gerald Jay Sussman, Julie Sussman

  Русский перевод: *Структура и Интерпретация Компьютерных Программ.*  Харольд Абельсон, Джеральд Джей Сассман

## Алгоритмы и структуры данных

- *Data Structures & Algorithms in Java*. Robert Lafore. 2002

  Русский перевод: *Структуры данных и алгоритмы Java.* Роберт Лафоре. 2012 г.

  Один из самых простых и доходчивых учебников в этой области. Все темы детально объяснены без единой формулы. Каждая глава сопровождается демонстрационным примером, визуально показывающим пошаговую работу рассматриваемых алгоритмов.
- *The Algorithm Design Manual*. Steven S Skiena. 2008

  Русский перевод: *Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке.* Стивен Скиена. 2014 г.
- *Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition*. Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford Stein. 2009

  Русский перевод: *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ.* Томас Х. Кормен, Чарльз И. Лейзерсон, Рональд Л. Ривест, Клиффорд Штайн. 2015 г.
- *The Art of Computer Programming*.  Donald E. Knuth. 2011

  Русский перевод: *Искусство программирования.* Дональд Э. Кнут. 2015 г.
- *Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs.* Niklaus Wirth, 1976 (or *Algorithms + Data Structures.* 2004.

  Русский перевод: *Алгоритмы + структуры данных = программы.* М.: Мир, 1985, *Алгоритмы и структуры данных.* М.: Мир, 1989, *Алгоритмы и структуры данных. Новая версия для Оберона.* М.: ДМК Пресс, 2010. Старая версия книги, в отличие от новых, содержит подробно разобранный компилятор простого языка.

## Проектирование и стиль кода

- *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*. Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides

  Русский перевод: *Приёмы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования.* Эрих Гамма, Ричард Хелм, Ральф Джонсон, Джон Влиссидс
- *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*. Martin Fowler

  Русский перевод: *Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений.* Мартин Фаулер
- *Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software*. Eric Evans

  Русский перевод: *Предметно-ориентированное проектирование. Структуризация сложных программных систем*. Эрик Эванс
- *«Совершенный код» (Code Complete)*. Стив Макконнелл
- *«Рефакторинг. Улучшение существующего кода»*. Мартин Фаулер
- *«Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг» (Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship)*. Роберт Мартин

## Навыки разработчика

- Эндрю Хант, Дэвид Томас — «Программист-прагматик. Путь от подмастерья к мастеру»

## Организация процесса разработки

- Том ДеМарко — «Deadline. Роман об управлении проектами»
- Роберт Мартин — «Быстрая разработка программного обеспечения»
- Джоэл Спольски — «И снова о программировании».
- Джо Мараско — «IT-проекты. Фронтовые очерки»
- Стив Макконнелл — «Сколько стоит программный проект»
- Джин Ким, Кевин Бер, Джордж Спаффорд — «Проект «Феникс». Роман о том, как DevOps меняет бизнес к лучшему».

## Синтаксический разбор и компиляция

- *Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*,  Alfred V. Aho, Monica S. Lam, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey D. Ullman

  Русский перевод: *Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструментарий*, Альфред Ахо, Моника С. Лам, Рави Сети, Джеффри Ульман. Известна как «Книга Дракона».

Comment: Было бы неплохо узнать, какие из них переиздавались в этом десятилетии

Comment: @Oceinic: теория алгоритмов не слишком-то устарела за это десятилетие. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, А книжка 
Anany Levitin "Introduction to The Design & Analysis of Algorithms" 
(Первод - Ананий Левитин, "Алгоритмы. Введение в разработку и анализ", М., Вильямс, 2006)
Разве плоха? Или просто ее забыли? Может, стоит добавить в список?

Comment: А еще есть Седжвик - "Алгоритмы на С++", "Алгоритмы на Java" и т. д.

Comment: А, есть еще http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b - может, стоит объединить?

Answer (score 10):

Книжки и теория это хорошо, а для практики я рекомендую [проект Эйлера](http://projecteuler.net/archives) ([задачи на русском](http://euler.jakumo.org/problems/showall.html)).
В каждой задаче есть набор данных с готовым ответом, на котором можно обкатать алгоритм. Но задачи устроены так, что за вменяемое время в лоб не решаются, чтоб узнать ответ - часто приходится изобретать более  оптимальный алгоритм после того, как с тестовым набором данных у вас все сойдется.
Полученный ответ можно проверить, и если он правильный - то откроется ветка форума, где участники оставляют свои варианты решений на разных языках.
Рекомендую всем)