# Книги по теме "Алгоритмы"

Tags: алгоритм, математика, книги

По аналогии с вопросом о [книгах по C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1?s=1%7C1.4957), поскольку, порывшись, по алгоритмам такого вопроса не нашел, надеюсь, с моей стороны не будет слишком некорректным задать его и на него же ответить - в меру моей книжной полки, конечно :)

Итак - какие книги читать по алгоритмам?

Исправления, добавления и уточнения приветствуются.

Comment: Хм, а не нужно ли слить с [этим](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474415/10105)?

Comment: Я его не нашел, так как искал книги по алгоритмам. ОК, убираю свой вопрос.

Comment: @Harry лучше оттуда сюда перенести, список-то хороший у вас.

Comment: @VladD, я не уверен, что алгоритмам место в базовых знаниях. Лучше всё-таки отдельно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Почему бы и нет? Тогда надо кусок оттуда унести сюда.

Comment: @VladD, ага. Но нужно где-то обсудить?

Comment: @Qwertiy: В чате?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Для начинающих:**

- **Адитья Бхаргава Грокаем алгоритмы. Иллюстрированное пособие для программистов и любопытствующих.**
- **Д. Ахо, Дж. Хопкрофт, Д. Ульман - *Структуры данных и алгоритмы* - 2000.** Книга по азам алгоритмов; рабочий язык - Pascal.
- [**Джон Пол Мюллер, Лука Массарон - *Алгоритмы для чайников* - 2018.**](http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-9909446-2-6.html)
- [**Т. Кормен - *Алгоритмы. Вводный курс* - 2014.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1868-0.html) Фактически выжимка из более существенного труда по алгоритмам того же автора.
- [**А. Левитин - *Алгоритмы. Введение в разработку и анализ* - 2006.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0987-2.html)
  Просто и понятно об алгоритмах, с ориентацией *на методы разработки алгоритмов*.
- [**Красиковы И.В., И.Е. - *Алгоритмы. Просто как 2x2* - 2007.**](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135380989/)
- [**М.Эрвиг. *Занимательные алгоритмы* - 2019.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2090-4.html)

**Для среднего и более уровня:**

- **Б. Смит. - *Методы и алгоритмы вычисления на строках* - 2006.** Название говорит само за себя :)
- [**Г. Уоррен-мл. - *Алгоритмические трюки для программистов, 2-е изд.* - 2014.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1838-3.html) В первую очередь различные низкоуровневые фокусы с битами и байтами.
- [**Дж. Хайнеман, Г. Поллис, С. Селков - *Алгоритмы. Справочник*. - 2016**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-7-4.html). С примерами на С/С++, Java, Python. Самые разные алгоритмы (включая вычислительную геометрию, пространственные древовидные структуры, поиск путей в ИИ), но *очень* кратко.

Следующие книги в представлении не нуждаются :). Предупреждение - очень академичный труд, переполненный математикой.

- [**Д. Кнут - *Искусство программирования, том 1. Основные алгоритмы, 3-е изд.* - 2000.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/sci_Knuth1.html)
- [**Д. Кнут - *Искусство программирования, том 2. Получисленные алгоритмы, 3-е изд.* - 2000.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/sci_Knuth2.html)
- [**Д. Кнут - *Искусство программирования, том 3. Сортировка и поиск, 2-е изд.* - 2000.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/sci_Knuth3.html)
- [**Д. Кнут - *Искусство программирования, том 4,А. Комбинаторные алгоритмы, часть 1.* - 2013.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1744-7.html)

И еще несколько книг для высокого уровня.

- [**А.В. Ахо, М.С. Лам, Р. Сети, Д.Д. Ульман - *Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструментарий.* - 2008.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1349-4.html) Грамматики, языки, лексические и синтаксические анализаторы, генераторы кода, оптимизация.
- [**Т. Кормен, Ч. Лейзерсон, Р. Ривест, К. Штайн - *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ. 3-е изд.* - 2013.**](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html) Капитальный труд, с массой теории, хотя и не столь академичный, как творение Д. Кнута.

Comment: конкретная математика - на самом деле - в ту же степь

Comment: Не хватает 3 книжек - [Algorithms (4th Edition)](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) (по этой книге ещё и курсы на курсере есть: [раз](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1), [два](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part2)), [The Algorithm Design Manual, 2nd Edition](http://www.algorist.com/) - маст рид, это даже рекрутеры советуют почитать, [Алгоритмы](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27676529/) - по этой книге есть [курс на степике](https://stepik.org/course/63/)

Comment: @m0d Это общий ответ, исправьте, добавьте...

Comment: @Harry, можно ли в этот список внести книгу под названием ``"Теория категорий для программистов"``?

Comment: Люди, это общий ответ, каждый сам вносит в него исправления. Если боится - составляет свой собственный :)