# Что такое алгоритм?

Tags: алгоритм, терминология

Что такое алгоритм? Глава в книге началась практически со слов:

> измерение эффективности алгоритмов by Big O Notation

Но там не рассказывали, что такое алгоритм.

Comment: Ну, google://define+algorithm выдало мне «Процесс или набор правил, необходимых для проведения расчета или выполнения какой-либо задачи.»

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*С алгоритмами мы сталкиваемся практически каждый день. Иногда даже сами того не осознавая. Например, когда просим кого-то купить продукты в магазине. Мы объясняем, какие нужны продукты, сколько их, какие требования к ним мы предъявляем. К примеру: купить две буханки чёрного хлеба, причём свежего.*

*Мы указываем чёткий алгоритм: необходимо зайти в магазин, узнать, есть ли чёрный хлеб. Затем узнать, свежий ли этот хлеб. А уже после этого (в случае двух положительных ответов) купить две буханки.*

*Даже краткое описание этой обыденной для каждого из нас процедуры достаточно объёмно. Что же тогда говорить об инструкциях пользователя, которые являются примерами более сложных алгоритмов?*

Рекомендую - раз само понятие **алгоритм** вызывает непонимание - начать с этого [урока](http://interneturok.ru/informatika/6-klass/algoritm-i-ispolniteli/chto-takoe-algoritm). *Я не шучу и не издеваюсь.*

И, кстати, вот тут есть список книг, которые, возможно, имеет смысл посмотреть - [Книги по теме "Алгоритмы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Answer (score 3):

[Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC) дает такое определение

> Алгори́тм — набор инструкций, описывающих порядок действий исполнителя для достижения некоторого результата. В старой трактовке вместо слова «порядок» использовалось слово «последовательность», но по мере развития параллельности в работе компьютеров слово «последовательность» стали заменять более общим словом «порядок». Независимые инструкции могут выполняться в произвольном порядке, параллельно, если это позволяют используемые исполнители.

Comment: там похоже забыли ключевое - Алгори́тм — набор инструкций, **однозначно понятных исполнителю**, описывающих...

Comment: Т.е. еффективный алгоритм доступа или алгоритм сортировки это еффекивная последовательность действий, для достижения лучшего результата?

Comment: Для чего и где они вообще используются? Часто их встречал в статьях.

Comment: эффективный - значит он работает достаточно хорошо и быстро. И сокрее всего на данный момент более быстрых не нашли.

Comment: @KoVadim более быстрых чем кто?

Comment: чем другие известные алгоритмы.

Comment: @антонсорокин не "лучшего результата". Как бы Вы не сортировали, у Вас всегда получится одна и та же отсортированная последовательность. Эффективный алгоритм - это алгоритм, который для достижения цели расходует меньше всего ресурсов. А ресурсы могут быть разные. Чаще всего - это время выполнения. Но бывают и другие: использование памяти, обращение к диску, обращение к сети...

Answer (score 0):

Эффективность алгоритмов измеряется его "сложностью".
Сложность может быть временна́я, по памяти, по размеру программы, вычислительная и др.
Для удобства используют нотацию О

Советую посмотреть от Яндекса курс по Алгоритмам. Там первая лекция как раз об этом.

PS *не по теме, но "**Э**ффективных"*