# Решение задач на Графы С++

Tags: c++, графы

Помогите пожалуйста найти понятную литературу о Графах.
Можете объяснить хотя бы один пример на практике?
Как считать матрицу смежности или список смежности.
И какие алгоритмы более популярные?

Comment: В Википедии есть много примеров и ответов. Я думаю, это хороший вариант для старта (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Какой именно алгоритм Вы хотите понять?

Comment: Смотря на каком уровне. См. разную литературу тут - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B. Из всего списка рекомендовал бы в первую очередь *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ* Кормена и др.

Comment: @KoVadim, Дейкстры. Но мне важно также само решение задач.

Comment: @goodalien http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1033/241/info

Comment: желающим дать ответ: лучше внести эту информацию в [описание метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%8b/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Графы - достаточно большая и сложная тема. Но они позволяют решать много интересных задач. Изучать их можно многими способами

- читать википедию (да, да, вбиваем слово [граф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) и поехали).
- Пойти на мехмат (до 5-6 лет, некоторые считают это потерей времени)
- Пройти онлайн курсы, например, на [курсере](https://ru.coursera.org/learn/teoriya-grafov). Там как минимум сам план занятий уже полезен - можно составить список ключевых слов и понятий.
- Почитать умные книги. Гугл выдает очень много. А некоторые вузы даже [выкладывают свои методички](http://window.edu.ru/resource/360/60360/files/dln001.pdf)
- пойти на популярный сайт [по алгоритмам](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/) и зависнуть там на долго:) Там, кстати, есть и разбор аглоритма Дейкстры.
- узнать о [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) и научиться строить графы (даже [онлайн](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) (очень хороший инструмент для визуализации, сильно помогает понимать)

Comment: KoVadim пишет: "выкладывают свои методички". Там ошибка не стр.18 (Рис. 1.12): матрица смежности не соответствует графу :( , что не снижает актуальности Вашего ответа :-)

Comment: никто не исключал, что в методичках могут быть ошибки.