# Я создал идеальный алгоритм сортировки расческой?

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка, сложность

Код:

```
public static void raschestkaSort(int[] a){
    for(int d = a.length - 2; d >= 0; d--){
        for(int i = 0; i <= (a.length - 2) - d; i++){
            if(a[i] > a[i + d + 1]){
                swap(a, i, i + d + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void swap(int[] a, int from, int to) {
    int temp = a[from];
    a[from] = a[to];
    a[to] = temp;
}
```

В наихудшем случае сложность алгоритма должна быть равна `O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1))`. [В вики же](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Java) - `O(n^2)`. Может, я неправильно считаю сложность?

P.S.: И действительно, если запустить сортировку с таким кодом:

```
public static void raschestkaSort(int[] a){
    int countOfComparing = 0;
    for(int d = a.length - 2; d >= 0; d--){
        for(int i = 0; i <= (a.length - 2) - d; i++){
            countOfComparing++;
            if(a[i] > a[i + d + 1]){
                swap(a, i, i + d + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(countOfComparing);
}
```

То для 14 элементов сравнений будет 91. А это близко не `O(n^2)`

Comment: `1+2+3+...+(n-1) = (n-1)*n/2`  Вопросы есть?

Comment: @Harry Так, это будет `(1 + (n - 1)) * n/2`, я ошибаюсь?

Comment: то есть `n^2 / 2`, но это же все равно меньше, чем в вики. В целых 2 раза

Comment: @Miron, там не просто так считается, как обычное уравнение. Там берется самый большой степень, т.е. 1/2 мы упускаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В асимптотической сложности константы нужно отбрасывать. Асимптотическая сложность - это относительная величина. Она определяет кол-во единиц времени. которое понадобится для выполнения алгоритма.
Думаю, это нужно проиллюстрировать - например, у нас есть ф-ция `f(n)`, принимающая количество раз, которое нужно вывести строку `"Hello world"`. Кол-во единиц времени, которое займет выполнение зависит только от числа n. И зависит напрямую - значит сложность будет напрямую зависеть от числа `n`, и, соответственно, будет равна `O(n)`.
Зависит же кол-во единиц времени в случае с сортировкой массива алгоритмом `raschestkaSort(a)` ТОЛЬКО от размерности `a`. Возьмем размерность за число `n`. Кол-во единиц времени, которое займет выполнение зависит только от числа `n`. И зависит оно в следующем отношении - `(1 + (n - 1)) * n/2 = n * n / 2` - это и есть `O`. То есть `O(n * n / 2)`. Вспомним, в асимптотической сложности константы нужно отбрасывать. Тогда `O(n * n)`. То есть та же сложность. что и в вики.

Comment: Кроме первой фразы, остальное - набор слов. Что за `то есть k=n`??

Comment: @MBo почти полностью поменял текст.

Comment: `n` в `f(n)` в примере со строкой - это число букв в строке. Вывод целиком зависит линейно от количество символов, т.е. `O(n)`.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica n - это "количество раз, которое нужно вывести строку "Hello world"".

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. чистое O(n^2)

Далее,  O(n^2) не означает, что надо возвести n в квадрат, и это и будет число сравнений. Попробуйте несколько раз увеличить n раз в 5 и посмотрите на результаты...

[Почитайте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5), что означает запись O(f(n)).

И 1000000000n^2+100n, и n^2/100000000+100n - это все O(n^2).

P.S. И вообще, давно и строго доказано, что алгоритм сортировки, основанный на сравнениях, не может быть лучше O(N * log N)...

Comment: Почитал. "с увеличением параметра n, характеризующего количество входной информации алгоритма, время работы алгоритма будет возрастать не быстрее, чем некоторая константа, умноженная на f(n);" - все четко. наша константа указывает на скорость, с которой возрастает сложность. Неужели в нашем случае это не так - есть что-то еще кроме операций сравнения, на что нужно обращать внимание при оценке сложности?(неужели это КОЛИЧЕСТВО СВАПОВ? Тогда все сходится!(или нет?)).

Comment: Понимаете, ну нет тут конкретной константы. Как вот, например, вы не задумывались, почему в O(n*log n) **не указывается**, какой именно логарифм? Потому что это неважно - любые два логарифма с разными основаниями отличаются на константный множитель. Ну неважно это - n^2/2 или 10000n^2. Главное - вид зависимости...

Comment: Имеете ввиду производную?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что `n^2 / (n-1)^2` просто должна быть константой?

Comment: Да при чем тут производная... Разве что в правиле Лопиталя :)  Почитайте первую главу этой книги: https://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/cormen.pdf

Comment: Прочитал полностью. Формула сложности(в их понимании) - это просто количество строк, пройденное программой. Мы же считаем количество сравнений, ибо изменяются только они(за исключением кол-ва вызовов swap). Почему я сделал предположение о производной ? Потому, что производная - это скорость возрастания ф-ции. И это вполне вяжется с нашей концепцией сложности - например, для O(n^2) производная будет равна n, а для O(n * (n-1) / 2) - (n - 1)/2. Могу ошибаться, с производной знаком только поверхностно.

Comment: Ничего вы так и не поняли... Посмотрите себе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576507/195342)  книгу попроще, и все же постарайтесь врубиться в то, что такое сложность алгоритма...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3ghq2E9tPw - посмотрел, и, вроде, понятно. n - это что-то входящее, например, размерность массива(увеличивающая на k при своем увеличении на единицу). O(kn) - это относительное время выполнения. Например, один и тот же алгоритм будет выполняться на машине в 100 раз мощней в 100 раз быстрей. k - это то, на сколько в этих относительных единицах будет увеличиваться время выполнения при увеличении n на 1. Вот и все.

Comment: В нашем же случае при увеличении n на 1 скорость выполнения увеличивается на `(n-1)/2`, то есть `k = (n-1)/2`. То есть это O(((n-1) / 2) * n) сложность.Разве не так?

Comment: Вы не хотите врубиться в главное - в то, что никто никакие действия, вообще говоря, не считает. И не бывает O(3n^2+n-15), например. Это просто O(n^2). Учительствовать я не могу, а потому простите, но больше участвовать в этой сказке про белого бычка не буду.

Comment: А, не до конца досмотрел. Константы можно откинуть. А вот то, что НЕЛИНЕЙНО зависит от n, нужно оставить.