# В чем заключается суть алгоритма перестановок?

Tags: алгоритм

Начинаю изучать новые алгоритмы, однако очень плохо воспринимаю языки кроме c# и Java

Недавно задался вопросом о том как создать List из всех перестановок в массиве; однако в интернете увидел множество совершенно не понятного чтива, к тому же я по большей части визуал.

Можете пожалуйста доступным языком объяснить этот алгоритм на пальцах

Пример : Для массива {1,2,3}
Результат :

```
{123}
{213}
{132}
{231}
{312}
{321}
```

Хотелось бы реализовать функцию, которая возвращает List со всеми перестановками элементов массива

```
public static List<string> Combinations(int[] array){
 throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" Лафоре, в ней очень просто и доходчиво это описано, а примеры все на Java.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, постараюсь найти эту книгу и прочитать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576507/228791