# разработка графики в gamedev С++

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

Просматривал вакансии в ААА-студиях в gamedev - достаточно часто требуется программист игровой графики С++. Но опыт колоссальный нужен.
Может кто обрисовать roadmap по этому направлению? Ну или хотя бы советы начинающему заниматься графикой. (какой фреймворки, библиотеки, другие языки, образование) т.к. в СНГ почти нет ААА-студий, есть альтернативы где можно начинать опыт набирать? Где еще востребована эта специальность?

Comment: где начать набирать опыт я имею ввиду сферу - а не конкретные компании

Comment: Тут часть вопросов не по программированию, на часть невозможно дать объективный ответ, а все вместе -- вопрос слишком широкий

Comment: https://github.com/utilForever/game-developer-roadmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В СНГ всё же есть геймдев компании, может и не ААА класса, но всё же довольно неплохие, куда можно устроиться и набираться практического опыта, перенимать знания и навыки.

По скиллам дорожная карта примерно такая:

1. Собственно знание C++, возможно современных стандартов, STL, возможно низкоуровневых моментов вроде [ASM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) и библиотек для работы с различными ресурсами: Assimp, FreeImage, FreeType.
2. Хорошее знание структур данных и алгоритмов. Например, см. [Книги по теме Алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576507/198251). Практиковаться можно на [ЛитКоде](https://leetcode.com) и подобных сайтах.
3. Хорошее знание графического конвейера, [OpenGL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) последних стандартов, [шейдеров и GLSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80).
4. Хорошее знание хотя бы одного игрового движка: Unity и, особенно для Плюсов, UnrealEngine, Godot. При желании можно начать и с 2D: Box2D, Cocos2D, SFML.
5. Будет не лишним понимание сопряжённой геометрической математики (векторы, матрицы, [однородные координаты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82), [афинные](https://compgraphics.info/3D/) [преобразования](http://window.edu.ru/resource/898/72898/files/stup559.pdf)), а также физики света и формулы, алгоритмы для её симуляции (хотя бы [алгоритмы затенения Фонга, Гуро](https://compgraphics.info/3D/)).
   Можно ещё попробовать базово освоить 3Д моделирование и анимацию, чтобы лучше понимать коллег по цеху, иметь материал для практики, и разобраться с текстурами, материалами.

Для успешного построения карьеры геймдев-разработчика зарубежом скорее всего в любом случае придётся набираться основному опыту самостоятельно. Если навыков промышленной разработки пока нет, то для начала можно пойти и в классическую компанию, где развить основные навыки разработки до уровня нормального middle developer'a. Затем надо идти в геймдев индустрию; если повезёт, то можно и сразу, на джуна, но только если компания хорошая, способная научить best practices. А там, ближе к уровню senior, уже видно будет `;)`

Comment: написано конечно красиво. А потом на собеседование приходит сеньор, спрашиваешь "вот есть два игрока на 2д карте, координаты x и y для них известны, как найти расстояние по **прямой**?". и такое выдают...  По факту - написанное нужно только, если идти в разработку движков и подобного. Но там своя кухня и просто так с улицы не берут. А если делать интерфейс пользователя, банальную логику, настройки, то 3/4 выше написанного никогда не понадобится.

Comment: @KoVadim ага, а потом такого разработчика игровой графики попросят сделать красивый эффект прицела как в настоящей линзе, а он матрицы преобразований с однородными координатамии не понимает, попросишь его bloom filter добавить с какими-то нестандартными особенностями, а он в шейдеры не шарит, только примитивный код копипастить может. Этим и отличается senior разраб, обширными познаниями, в том числе теоретическими, что делает его готовым к любым сложным задачам, а не только интерфейсики клепать.

Comment: Вы смешали две задачи в одну:) Там есть задача самого прицела и его отрисовки. И это решает две различные команды. А вот зачем нам bloom фильтр к прицелу... я не знаю. Может blur? Вы точно разработчик игр?

Comment: 1. Я и не говорил, что bloom filter нужен прицелу, просто упомянул пару задач из компьютерной графики, где нужна хорошая база. 2. Нет, гейм.дев для меня лишь хобби с несколькими пройденными курсами и проектами, но знакомые в индустрии есть, и только в самых топовых компаниях имеется такое сильное разделение по узким направлениям, в мелких, средних и многих крупных актуальны более обширные познания. Более того, технологии у всех разные, какие проекты и задачи попадутся и какие варианты развития выбирать – это уже на выбор ОП, я лишь обрисовал основные понятия, тематики и возможные направления.

Comment: bloom фильтр - это больше к базам данных. Для меня геймдейв - каждодневная работа:)

Comment: Тот скорее к структурам данных в целом, а не чисто к БД. Вы наверное бэкэнд разработчик, а не по графике? Человеку из темы вспомнился бы [другой bloom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect)) `(:`

Comment: я 3д графику глубоко не хожу, хотя и приходится трогать немного. Мне в пользовательском интерфейсе хватает. А бэкенд разработкой я занимался когда то давно, но особой (пхп выпиливал:) )